# Explicit Type Conversion in Scala

Tags: scala, type-conversion

Lets say I have the following code:

```
abstract class Animal
case class Dog(name:String) extends Animal
var foo:Animal = Dog("rover")
var bar:Dog = foo //ERROR!
```

How do I fix the last line of this code?  Basically, I just want to do what, in a C-like language would be done:

```
var bar:Dog = (Dog) foo
```

Answer (score 149, accepted):

I figured this out myself.  There are two solutions:

1) Do the explicit cast:

```
var bar:Dog = foo.asInstanceOf[Dog]
```

2) Use pattern matching to cast it for you, this also catches errors:

```
var bar:Dog = foo match {
  case x:Dog => x
  case _ => {
    // Error handling code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Note, that second way is error-prone on generics due to JVM type erasure

Comment: @om-nom-nom may you explain it a little bit? thanks.

Comment: @WeihongDiao please, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete

Comment: @om-nom-nom: Would it be valid to combine 1) and 2) to `var bar:Dog = foo match {
  case x:Dog => foo.asInstanceOf[Dog]
  case _ => {
    // Error handling code here
  }
}` ?

Comment: @Make42 you don't need to make cast, just use `x` from pattern matching

Comment: @om-nom-nom: You said that the pattern matching is not error-prone - I thought the cast might be, or did I get that wrong? Thus I thought combining the two might eliminate all error-prone-ness?

Comment: @Make42 checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056645/how-to-pattern-match-on-generic-type-in-scala and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246734/scala-pattern-match-a-function-how-to-get-around-type-erasure to get a sense of kind of problems you can have