# Scala equivalent of Java java.lang.Class<T> Object

Tags: java, class, scala

The question is best explained by an example:

In Java for a JPA EntityManager, I can do the following(Account is my Entity class):

```
Account result = manager.find(Account.class, primaryKey);
```

In Scala, my naive attempt is:

```
val result = manager.find(Account.class, primaryKey)
```

But when I try to use `Account.class` in Scala, it seems to not like this.  How can I specify the java.lang.Class object for the Account class in Scala?

Comment: VonC already provided the answer, but take a look at my own [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-parameter) on Scala & Erasure. I think it might provide you with ideas to do things in a different way than what you are trying.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68914075

Answer (score 271, accepted):

According to "[The Scala Type System](http://web.archive.org/web/20100601092747/http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch12.html)",

```
val c = new C
val clazz = c.getClass              // method from java.lang.Object
val clazz2 = classOf[C]             // Scala method: classOf[C] ~ C.class
val methods = clazz.getMethods      // method from java.lang.Class<T>
```

> The `classOf[T]` method returns the runtime representation for a Scala type. It is analogous to the Java expression `T.class`.
> Using `classOf[T]` is convenient when you have a type that you want information about, while `getClass` is convenient for retrieving the same information from an instance of the type.

However, `classOf[T]` and `getClass` return slightly different values, reflecting the effect of type erasure on the JVM, in the case of getClass.

```
scala> classOf[C]
res0: java.lang.Class[C] = class C

scala> c.getClass
res1: java.lang.Class[_] = class C
```

That is why the [following will not work](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/626.html):

```
val xClass: Class[X] = new X().getClass //it returns Class[_], nor Class[X]

val integerClass: Class[Integer] = new Integer(5).getClass //similar error
```

There is a [ticket regarding the return type of `getClass`](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/490).

([James Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73046/james-moore) reports that the ticket is "now", ie Nov. 2011, two years later, fixed.
In 2.9.1, `getClass` now does:

```
scala> "foo".getClass 
       res0: java.lang.Class[_ <: java.lang.String] = class java.lang.String
```

)

Back in 2009:

> It would be useful if Scala were to treat the return from getClass() as a java.lang.Class[T] forSome { val T : C } where C is something like the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called
>
> It would let me do something like the following where I want to introspect on a class but shouldn't need a class instance.
> I also want to limit the types of classes I want to introspect on, so I use Class[_ <: Foo]. But this prevents me from passing in a Foo class by using Foo.getClass() without a cast.

Note: regarding `getClass`, a possible workaround would be:

```
class NiceObject[T <: AnyRef](x : T) {
  def niceClass : Class[_ <: T] = x.getClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
}

implicit def toNiceObject[T <: AnyRef](x : T) = new NiceObject(x)

scala> "Hello world".niceClass                                       
res11: java.lang.Class[_ <: java.lang.String] = class java.lang.String
```

Comment: FYI, The ticket @VonC mentioned was marked fixed on 22/Jun/11.  In 2.9.1, getClass now does: scala> "foo".getClass
res0: java.lang.Class[_ <: java.lang.String] = class java.lang.String

Answer (score 51):

`classOf[Account]` in Scala is equivalent to `Account.class` in Java.