# passing current class as argument in scala

Tags: scala

How to pass current class as argument? In java we do:

```
mymethod (this.class)
```

or

```
mymethod (MyClass.class)
```

How can I pass a scala current class to this method?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135248/scala-equivalent-of-java-java-lang-classt-object

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`this.getClass` or `classOf[MyClass]`