# How to `getClass` of a `case class` without constructing one?

Tags: scala, reflection, case-class

Suppose you have a Scala case class like this:

```
case class A(a: Int, b: Int)
```

How to get the `Class` representation of it, the one you usually get with `.getClass`?

**What does NOT work:**

Calling `A.getClass` will not give you the class information, but rather the accompanying auto-generated object. You can observe it by calling: `A.getClass.getDeclaredFields.toList`, which will give you this list: `List(public static A$ A$.MODULE$)` instead of `a` and `b` fields.

Calling `A(null, null).getClass` does work because we instantiate a dummy object, but it's more verbose, feels dirty, and comes at odds with compiler linters like "wartremover".

Comment: @Thilo Could be. It was absolutely not google-able to me though. I used keywords like "getClass scala case class". Not sure myself if it should be closed as duplicate or better leave.

Comment: @Thilo the problem, I think, is that the linked question requires **java** knowledge. Which some may not have, or some may already have forgotten. My question, however, targets a different audience -- pure Scala users.

Comment: Object#getClass is a Java method to begin with, though, and mostly used for reflection. Pure Scala users would not normally use (or even know about) it.

Comment: Maybe this thread is closer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875065/passing-current-class-as-argument-in-scala

Comment: It is a duplicate (because there is another question with an answer that completely answers this question), but signpost duplicates are completely OK if it helps other people to find the answer with the search engines. Upvoted it so it's not roomba'd.

Answer (score 2):

Use Scala-s built-in `classOf[A]`. The correct type will then be automatically inserted by the Scala compiler.

Comment: Note that this works with any class, not just with a case class.