# Scala getting the class of a parameter

Tags: scala

So in Java I had a class that contained a HashMap that used the class as a key pointing to an object of the same class.

```
class ComponentContainer {
  private HashMap<Class<? extends Component>, Component> componentMap

  public ComponentContainer {
    componentMap = new HashMap<Class<? extends Component>, Component>();
  }

  public void set (Component c) {
    componentMap.put(c.getClass(), c);
  }
}
```

However when I try to do the same thing in Scala within a trait I find myself getting a type mismatch error that a java.lang.Class[?0] was found where Class[Component] was needed.

```
trait ComponentContainer {
  val componentMap: HashMap[Class[Component], Component] = HashMap.empty

  def set (c: Component) {
    val t = (c.getClass, c)
    componentMap += t
  }    
}
```

This has me absolutely stumped any help would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't compile is that `T.getClass` method has result `Class[_]` and not `Class[T]`. Details of getClass has been explained by VonC [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135248/scala-equivalent-of-java-java-lang-classt-object/1135317#1135317).

From your source code I cannot see if you care about type parameter of Class instances but following version of your code compiles:

```
trait ComponentContainer {
  val componentMap: HashMap[Class[_], Component] = HashMap.empty

  def set (c: Component) {
    val t = (c.getClass, c)
    componentMap += t
  }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. I don't think I'll have any reason to worry about type parameters of components. It all seems so obvious once someone points it out to you. Cheers!