# How to get the class of a singleton object at compile time?

Tags: class, scala, programming-languages, singleton, language-design

Consider something like this:

```
object Singleton

val cls: Class[Singleton] = ???
```

What do I have to write instead of `???`?

I tried `classOf[Singleton]`, `classOf[Singleton.type]`, `Singleton.type`, but nothing worked.

(I know of course about `getClass`, the runtime version of `classOf`, but that's not what I'm asking.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here a solution, but it's not pretty ...

```
object Singleton

val cls : Class[Singleton] = Singleton.getClass.asInstanceOf[Class[Singleton]]
```

Edit: completed the solution after reading another question/answer: [Scala equivalent of Java java.lang.Class<T> Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135248/scala-equivalent-of-java-java-lang-classt-object)

Note1: type erasure would prevent this from being particularly useful, e.g. in pattern matching. See referenced question/answer, above, for a good explanation

Note2: the `scala -explaintypes` flag is quite handy in understanding type errors.

HTH

Comment: `.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]` does not appear to be needed for this to work.

Answer (score 4):

You are not alone with this problem. The answer is: There is currently no way to avoid a `Singleton.getClass`. See [this](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2453?focusedCommentId=46608&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-46608) comment for more information why `classOf[Singleton]` does not work