# How to specify Foo.class in scala?

Tags: java, scala

I am using java API that looks like:

```
import com.google.code.morphia.Morphia;

.....

     val morphia = new Morphia();
     morphia.map(Hotel.class).map(Address.class);
```

but it gives scala compiler error.
what is the correct code in scala for above? Note that .map is defined as part of
morphia API and not to be confused with scala map.

Comment: What compile error do yo get?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your problem is with the `.class` parts, the Scala equivalent of `Hotel.class` would be `classOf[Hotel]`, likewise for `Address`.

Hopefully this should fix your problem, although it's hard to tell without seeing the full compiler output.

Comment: This fixed the compiler error. Hopefully I will also not get runtime error when I complete the code.

Comment: Its unfortunate that scala chose this format which requires almost twice as much typing than in standard Java. I though scala requires less typing.

Comment: Scala *does* require less typing; in practice, you'll find that the `classOf[T]` construct is almost never needed.  The usual technique to deal with type-dependent logic in Scala is pattern matching.

Comment: @amc Scala does not have static methods, since static methods don't make sense in an object oriented environment (what's their `this`?). So `ClassName.class` doesn't make sense -- it can't be a static method, and `ClassName` is not an object. On the other hand, `classOf[T]` is a method on object `Predef`, so it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `classOf[Hotel]`

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: After having looked at the API; what you actually want is:

```
classOf[T]
```

eg.

```
classOf[Hotel]
```

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135248/scala-equivalent-of-java-java-lang-classt-object/1135317#1135317) on Scala’s typesystem.

---

*Wrong answer, but maybe useful, if someone is mislead by this questions title:*

`class` is a reserved word in Scala. If you want to use it as a field or method name, you need to enclose it with backticks:

```
Hotel.`class`
```