# How to construct the Scala Form using a Java class in Play

Tags: java, forms, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a Java class like:

```
public class User {
   public String name;
   public String email;
}
```

Instead of creating another case class in Scala or using `tuple`, can I do something like

```
Form<User> form = Form.form(User.class)
```

The above code is possible in Play Java but not for Scala

Comment: Just an idea, but should work: What happens if you just import the Java form class and use it (i.e. use `play.data.Form` instead of the default one for Scala, `play.api.data.Form`)? You should be able to use that one from Scala exactly like from Java. Well, almost exactly, more like `form:Form[User] = Form.form(User.class)`

Comment: @Carsten I tried but Scala didn't allow me to use .class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135248/scala-equivalent-of-java-java-lang-classt-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.class` isn't a keyword in Scala. Try `classOf[User]`.

i.e.

```
val form = Form.form(classOf[User])
```