# Scala equivalent of User.class

Tags: scala

How do you get the class in scala equivalent to `User.class`?

Apparently this is too short even though it's just a really really really short little concise little question that doesn't require elaboration...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala equivalent of Java java.lang.Class<T> Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135248/scala-equivalent-of-java-java-lang-classt-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `classOf`:

```
val cls = classOf[User]
```