# not able to load graph to janusgraph from spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, gremlin, janusgraph

I am trying to test graphofgodsfactory example using spark/scala/janusgraph using hbase as backend storage.

My code : samplejanusloading.scala

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.rddToPairRDDFunctions
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.plugin.AbstractGremlinPlugin;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.plugin.IllegalEnvironmentException;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.plugin.PluginAcceptor;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.plugin.PluginInitializationException;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.process.computer.TinkerGraphComputer;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.FileConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.concurrent.BasicThreadFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner;
import org.apache.spark.Partitioner;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher;
import org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer;
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.Constants;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.process.computer.AbstractHadoopGraphComputer;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.process.computer.util.ComputerSubmissionHelper;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.HadoopConfiguration;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.HadoopGraph;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.io.FileSystemStorage;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.io.GraphFilterAware;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.io.HadoopPoolShimService;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.io.VertexWritable;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.util.ConfUtil;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.computer.ComputerResult;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.computer.GraphComputer;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.computer.MapReduce;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.computer.Memory;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.computer.VertexProgram;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.computer.util.DefaultComputerResult;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.computer.util.MapMemory;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.TraversalStrategies;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.TraversalInterruptedException;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.process.computer.payload.ViewIncomingPayload;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.process.computer.traversal.strategy.SparkVertexProgramInterceptor;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.process.computer.traversal.strategy.optimization.SparkInterceptorStrategy;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.process.computer.traversal.strategy.optimization.SparkSingleIterationStrategy;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.structure.Spark;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.structure.io.InputFormatRDD;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.structure.io.InputOutputHelper;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.structure.io.InputRDD;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.structure.io.OutputFormatRDD;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.structure.io.OutputRDD;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.structure.io.PersistedInputRDD;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.structure.io.PersistedOutputRDD;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.structure.io.SparkContextStorage;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.structure.io.gryo.GryoRegistrator;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.structure.io.gryo.kryoshim.unshaded.UnshadedKryoShimService;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Direction;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.IoRegistry;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.Storage;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.kryoshim.KryoShimServiceLoader;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraph._;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraph;
import org.janusgraph.diskstorage;
import org.janusgraph.graphdb;
import org.janusgraph.util;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory._;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory;
import org.janusgraph.core.attribute.Geo;
import org.janusgraph.core.attribute.Geoshape;
import org.janusgraph.example.GraphOfTheGodsFactory;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.T;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{HBaseAdmin,HTable,Put,Get}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
object samplejanusloading {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {

/*    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)     
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)*/
    //Start the Spark context
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("Janusgraph")
      .setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlcontext = new SQLContext(sc)     


val confg = new HBaseConfiguration()
val admin = new HBaseAdmin(confg)



val grap = JanusGraphFactory.open("c:\\janusgraph\\conf\\janusgraph-hbase.properties")


println("factry open")
val mgmt = grap.openManagement()
println("factry opened")
val name = mgmt.makePropertyKey("name")
println("first key property ")

val age = mgmt.makePropertyKey("age").make();
val reason = mgmt.makePropertyKey("reason").make();
val place = mgmt.makePropertyKey("place").make();


println("first edges open")
mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("father").make()
println("first edges open")
        mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("mother").make()
        mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("battled").make();
       //   mgmt.buildEdgeIndex(battled, "battlesByTime")
        mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("lives").make();
        mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("pet").make();
        mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("brother").make();


println("edges open")
        mgmt.makeVertexLabel("titan").make();
        mgmt.makeVertexLabel("location").make();
        mgmt.makeVertexLabel("god").make();
        mgmt.makeVertexLabel("demigod").make();
        mgmt.makeVertexLabel("human").make();
        mgmt.makeVertexLabel("monster").make();
println("vrtx open")
        mgmt.commit();
        println("cmt open")
        val tx = grap.newTransaction();
 val saturn = tx.addVertex(T.label, "titan", "name", "saturn", "age", "100");
        val sky = tx.addVertex(T.label, "location", "name", "sky");
        val sea = tx.addVertex(T.label, "location", "name", "sea");
        val jupiter = tx.addVertex(T.label, "god", "name", "jupiter", "age", "5000");
        val neptune = tx.addVertex(T.label, "god", "name", "neptune", "age", "4500");
        val hercules = tx.addVertex(T.label, "demigod", "name", "hercules", "age", "30");
        val alcmene = tx.addVertex(T.label, "human", "name", "alcmene", "age", "45");
        val pluto = tx.addVertex(T.label, "god", "name", "pluto", "age", "4000");
        val nemean = tx.addVertex(T.label, "monster", "name", "nemean");
        val hydra = tx.addVertex(T.label, "monster", "name", "hydra");
        val cerberus = tx.addVertex(T.label, "monster", "name", "cerberus");
        val tartarus = tx.addVertex(T.label, "location", "name", "tartarus");

         jupiter.addEdge("father", saturn);
        jupiter.addEdge("lives", sky, "reason", "loves fresh breezes");
        jupiter.addEdge("brother", neptune);
        jupiter.addEdge("brother", pluto);

        neptune.addEdge("lives", sea).property("reason", "loves waves");
        neptune.addEdge("brother", jupiter);
        neptune.addEdge("brother", pluto);

        hercules.addEdge("father", jupiter);
        hercules.addEdge("mother", alcmene);
        hercules.addEdge("battled", nemean, "time", "1", "place", Geoshape.point(38.1f, 23.7f));
        hercules.addEdge("battled", hydra, "time", "2", "place", Geoshape.point(37.7f, 23.9f));
        hercules.addEdge("battled", cerberus, "time", "12", "place", Geoshape.point(39f, 22f));

        pluto.addEdge("brother", jupiter);
        pluto.addEdge("brother", neptune);
        pluto.addEdge("lives", tartarus, "reason", "no fear of death");
        pluto.addEdge("pet", cerberus);

        cerberus.addEdge("lives", tartarus);
println("done sir");

        // commit the transaction to disk
        tx.commit();
tx.close()




    sc.stop
  }
}
```

c:\janusgraph\conf\janusgraph-hbase.properties file :

```
    storage.backend=hbase
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory
gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.HadoopGraph
gremlin.hadoop.graphInputFormat=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.io.gryo.GryoInputFormat
gremlin.hadoop.graphOutputFormat=org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.NullOutputFormat
gremlin.hadoop.outputLocation=output
gremlin.hadoop.jarsInDistributedCache=true
spark.executor.memory=1g
spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
storage.hostname=127.0.0.1
cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.5
```

But its error while creating very second line inside janusgraphfactory.

i.e `val name = mgmt.makePropertyKey("name")`

output : factry open
factry opened

And I can see table names janusgraph created in hbase. but only few lines of graph config is loaded.

```
hbase(main):043:0> scan 'janusgraph'
ROW                        COLUMN+CELL                                                                
 configuration             column=s:cache.db-cache, timestamp=1507455998304001, value=\x8F\x01        
 configuration             column=s:cache.db-cache-clean-wait, timestamp=1507455998311001, value=\x8C\
                           xA8                                                                        
 configuration             column=s:cache.db-cache-size, timestamp=1507455998138001, value=\x94?\xE0\x
                           00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00                                                     
 configuration             column=s:cache.db-cache-time, timestamp=1507455998308001, value=\x8D\x80\x0
                           0\x00\x00\x00\x02\xBF                                                      
 configuration             column=s:graph.janusgraph-version, timestamp=1507455998362001, value=\x92\x
                           A00.1.\xB1                                                                 
 configuration             column=s:graph.timestamps, timestamp=1507455998395001, value=\xB6\x81      
 configuration             column=s:hidden.frozen, timestamp=1507455998404001, value=\x8F\x01         
 configuration             column=s:system-registration.c0a8ef013936-Praddy1.startup-time, timestamp=1
                           507456041876001, value=\xC1\x80\x00\x00\x00Y\xD9\xF4)\x06C5L\x80           
1 row(s) in 6.1320 seconds

hbase(main):044:0>
```

Error is :

Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`: Need to specify a datatype.

But when I try

`val name = mgmt.makePropertyKey("name").dataType(String).make()` . it doesnt do anything. but throws same error.

Need your help on what I am doing wrong . Bassically I am trying to develop spark program to create relation & save that to janusgraph in my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `classOf` in Scala ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135248/scala-equivalent-of-java-java-lang-classt-object)):

```
val name = mgmt.makePropertyKey("name").dataType(classOf[String]).make()
```

I'll also note that you have many extraneous properties in your `janusgraph-hbase.properties`. You should start with a minimal set of properties like the ones found in the properties files in the distribution.

```
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory
storage.backend=hbase
storage.hostname=127.0.0.1
storage.hbase.table=janusgraph
cache.db-cache=true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait=20
cache.db-cache-time=180000
cache.db-cache-size=0.5
```