# How to set HostnameVerifierClass in AkkaSSLConfig

Tags: java, scala, ssl, akka

as provided in [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/client-https-support.html) and [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/20381), I was trying to change `HostnameVerifierClass` using following code:

```
val sslConfig = AkkaSSLConfig().mapSettings { s =>
  s.withHostnameVerifierClass(java.lang.Class[NoopHostnameVerifier])
  s
}
val badCtx = Http().createClientHttpsContext(sslConfig)
Http().superPool[RequestTracker](badCtx)(httpMat)
```

But I am getting following error with this:

> Error:(83, 31) object java.lang.Class is not a value
>     s.withHostnameVerifierClass(JJClass[NoopHostnameVerifier])

Getting help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1135317), I changed it to:

```
val sslConfig = AkkaSSLConfig().mapSettings { s =>
  s.withHostnameVerifierClass(classOf[NoopHostnameVerifier])
  s
}
```

But this also does not compile saying:

> Error:(83, 38) type mismatch;
>
> found   : Classorg.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier
>
> required: Class[javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier]
>
> Note: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier <: javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier, but Java-defined class Class is invariant in type T.
>
> You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier`. (SLS 3.2.10)
>
> s.withHostnameVerifierClass(classOf[NoopHostnameVerifier])

How do I get around this, `NoopHostnameVerifier` implements interface `HostnameVerifier`, but still this error coming.

Comment: Have you seen [this issue](https://github.com/lightbend/ssl-config/issues/46), it seems to be about the same thing. Are you using the latest version of `ssl-config`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as suggested in comments, it was due to [issue](https://github.com/lightbend/ssl-config/issues/46) in ssl-config, by upgrading version to [0.2.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe/ssl-config-core_2.11/0.2.2), following code started working:

```
val sslConfig = AkkaSSLConfig().mapSettings { s =>
  s.withHostnameVerifierClass(classOf[VerifiesAllHostNames]) 
  s
}
```