# Convert class parameter from Java to Scala

Tags: java, scala

I have to convert this code from Java to Scala:

```
 Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc: ...");
 OlapConnection olapConnection = connection.unwrap(OlapConnection.class);
```

Problem is to convert the `unwrap` parameter. This is my attempt in Scala:

```scala
val connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc: ...")
val olapConnection = connection.unwrap(OlapConnection.getClass)
```

I get the error in  `OlapConnection.getClass` :

> value getClass is not a member of object org.olap4j.OlapConnection
>   Note that OlapConnection extends Any, not AnyRef. Such types can
>   participate in value classes, but instances cannot appear in singleton
>   types or in reference comparisons.

What is the equivalent of the unwrap parameter in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of Java's `T.class` in Scala would be [`classOf[T]`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Predef$.html):

```scala
val connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc: ...")
val olapConnection = connection.unwrap(classOf[OlapConnection])
```

*Note: not tested as I'm not sure what are your dependencies.*

Comment: More details in [this answer to "Scala equivalent of Java java.lang.Class<T> Object"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1135317/2707792).