# Pattern matching zero-argument functions in scala: mystified by warning

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I'm playing with scala's distributed actors.  Very nice.

I have a server which executes incoming function objects.
For example, the client has

```
object Tasks {
  def foo = {Console.println("I am Foo")};
  def bar = {Console.println("I am Bar");}
}

// In client actor...
...
  server ! Tasks.foo _
...
```

And the server can pick these up and execute them with actor code like

```
react {
  case task:(()=>Unit) =>
    task()
```

This all works nicely (which is very very cool indeed) but I'm mystified by a warning message output by `scalac` for the server code:

```
warning: non variable type-argument Unit in type pattern is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
        case task:(()=>Unit) =>
                     ^
```

How can I clean this warning up ?

(I'm pretty unclear on the difference between the `Unit` type, and the `()=>Unit` type of zero-argument functions.  Just trying to match `task:Unit` in the `react` is warning-free, but actually doesn't match the incoming tasks.)

Using Scala 2.7.5 on Debian, with Sun's Java6.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are really matching this:

```
case task:Function0[Unit] => task()
```

Due to erasure, Unit is not visible at runtime.
If you really don't care about the return type, you can do this in the react block:

```
case task:Function0[_] => task()
```

Answer (score 3):

This is complement to [@Mitch Blevins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534702/pattern-matching-zero-argument-functions-in-scala-mystified-by-warning/1534754#1534754)'s answer since his answer will get you through in this case.

See [How do I get around type erasure on Scala? Or, why can’t I get the type parameter of my collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-parameter) You probably have to pass around a tuple of `(Function0[T],Manifest[T])` to the actor. As you can see below, Scala is smart enough to deduce the type of `T` even if you just write `matchFunction(foo _)`.

```
scala> def foo = {Console.println("I am Foo")}
foo: Unit

scala> import scala.reflect.Manifest
import scala.reflect.Manifest

scala> def matchFunction[T](f: Function0[T])(implicit m : Manifest[T]) {
     |   (m,f) match {
     |     case (om: Manifest[_],of: Function0[_]) =>
     |       if(om <:< m) {
     |         of.asInstanceOf[Function0[T]]()
     |       }
     |   }
     | }
matchFunction: [T](() => T)(implicit scala.reflect.Manifest[T])Unit

scala> matchFunction(foo _)
I am Foo
```