# How to get the actual type of a generic type?

Tags: generics, scala

There is a class with generic type:

```
class Action[T]
```

Create some instances of it, put in a list:

```
val list = List(new Action[String], new Action[Int])
```

Iterate it, and how to get the actual type of the instances?

```
list foreach { action =>
     // how do I know the action is for a String or an Int?
}
```

Comment: What language are we talking about?

Comment: Can you use `action.getClass()`?

Comment: `action.getClass` can't tell the actual type

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Scala erases generic type parameters at compilation, so you would need to have some additional evidence in you object other than what traditional reflection provides. See:

[How do I get around type erasure on Scala? Or, why can't I get the type parameter of my collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-parameter)

This questions seems to imply there might be some magic to apply in some circumstances:

[Accounting for type parameters in a Scala generic class 'equals' method... are manifests the only way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283885/accounting-for-type-parameters-in-a-scala-generic-class-equals-method-are-ma)