# Scala generics - type mismatch error when passing high order function as parameter

Tags: scala

I'm trying to pass high order generic function to another generic function as parameter. However, I am quite unable to make it work. Following is sample code of what I am trying to achieve.

```
def foo[T](data: Seq[T]) = {
    //some codes 
}

def bar[U](id: Sring, fn: Seq[U] => Unit) = {
    criteria match {
      case x => data:Seq[String] = //some data; 
                fn(data)
      case b => data:Seq[Int] = //some data; 
                fn(data)
      case c => data:Seq[Char] = //some data; 
                fn(data)
    }
}

bar("123", foo)
```

> If I run the code, I will get error - Type mismatch - expected Seq[U] found - Seq[String]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val data` must be of type `U`, because that is the argument of `fn`:

```
def bar[U](id: Sring, fn: Seq[U] => Unit) = {
    val data: Seq[U] = //some data.
    fn(data) //I want U to be type of data i.e. Seq[String]
}
```

If you want `U` to be a `String`, then you must specify it when invoking `bar`.

```
bar[String]("123", foo)
```

This is defined on runtime so you can't decide inside of `bar` the type it should have. If you want it always to be a String, then simply remove `U`.

Comment: What if bar() invoke fn() dynamically? i.e. may pass different datatype sequence according to conditions to foo() e.g. Seq[String], Seq[Int], Seq[Char] etc. as I have updated in question.

Comment: @RaKa That's a whole different question. You need a classtag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400394/how-to-get-the-actual-type-of-a-generic-type What are you actually trying to achieve? It seems to me that you code could be greatly simplified without the generics

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense for `bar` to be generic while using the specific type `String` within it. `fn` is a `Seq[U] => Unit`, but you're passing it a very specific `Seq[String]`. `fn` will only work if `U = String`. What happens if `fn` is a `Seq[Int] => Unit`? The types aren't guaranteed to match.

Since the body of `bar` expects `fn` to accept a `Seq[String]`, the only thing you can really do is require `fn` to be a `Seq[String] => Unit`.

```
def foo[T](data: Seq[T]) = data.foreach(println)

def bar(id: String, fn: Seq[String] => Unit) = {
    val data: Seq[String] = List("a", "b", "c")
    fn(data)
}

scala> bar("123", foo)
a
b
c
```

Comment: what if bar() invoke fn() with multiple different data types. e.g. as you say Seq[Int]? Can, we make it work that way? because, I have match condition in bar function which generate different datatype sequence according to criteria and invoke fn().