# scala reflection

Tags: reflection, scala, hashmap

I want to create a hashmap to store parameters names and their values. The parameters however are with different types. I could use HashMap[String, Any], but I wouldn't know which types they are later on.  Is there anyway I can recovery the type information? Or is there any better way to store  pair?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get around type erasure on Scala? Or, why can't I get the type parameter of my collections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-parameter)

Comment: Were any of these answers useful to you? If not, do you have any feedback that would help us target your requirements better?

Comment: well, none of them really solved my problem. I was told (offline) by some people there is no elegant solution. I changed my design later to avoid such a problem...

Comment: What about using Daniel's solution, and changing `get` to return a pair of the key's value and the value's Manifest?

Answer (score 5):

Do you want access to the static type information, or the dynamic type information?  If you're after the former, you can use typed keys. Something along these lines should work:

```
final class Key[T]

object Registry {
   private var backingMap: Map[Key[_], _] = Map.empty

   def put[T](k: Key[T], v: T) = backingMap += (k -> v)

   def get[T](k: Key[T]): Option[T] = backingMap get k map (_.asInstanceOf[T])
}

scala> val strKey = new Key[String] 
strKey: Key[String] = Key@31028a

scala> val intKey = new Key[Int]
intKey: Key[Int] = Key@7ae77ca4

scala> Registry.put(strKey, "asdf")

scala> Registry.get(strKey)
res0: Option[String] = Some(asdf)

scala> Registry.put(intKey, "asdf")
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Key[Int]
 required: Key[Any]
       Registry.put(intKey, "asdf")
```

Alternately, you can use untyped keys and store the type information in the Map using manifests (as [Daniel suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-parameter/1094214#1094214)):

```
class Registry[K] {
   import scala.reflect.Manifest

   private var _map= Map.empty[K,(Manifest[_], Any)] 

   def put[T](key: K, item: T)(implicit m: Manifest[T]) {
      _map += (key -> (m, item))
   }

   def get[T](key:K)(implicit m : Manifest[T]): Option[T] = {
      for ((om, v) <- _map get key if om <:< m) 
         yield v.asInstanceOf[T]
   }
}
```

The latter approach has the advantage that you can use anything as a key, and you don't have to pass the original typed key objects around.  However, it has the drawback that you must specify the value type when you call the `get` method. If you specify the wrong type you'll get `None` just as if the key is not in the Registry at all, whereas with typed keys you're guaranteed to get any value associated with a key.

Answer (score 3):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-parameter/1094214#1094214), which implements exactly what you ask for.

Comment: Nice! I simplified your implementation somewhat in my answer and attempted to explain the differences between the typed key approach and the stored manifest approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have too many values, you may consider using a [HList](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=283&thread=238074) of Pairs or similar constructs.