# How to proxy a call to a hashmap without losing the type

Tags: scala, types

In the code below I get the correct type of the property (`PropertyA`) when I get it straight from the hashmap.

When I proxy this call through the get method in `ClassAbstract` the type is `PropertyAbstract[_ <: A]`

Is there a way to proxy the call to the hashmap and keep the correct type?

Another question is how can I add objects to the `revs` array with type checking?

```
class A
class B extends A
class C extends A

abstract class PropertyAbstract[T] {
  val revs = new java.util.ArrayList[T]
}

class PropertyA extends PropertyAbstract[B]
class PropertyB extends PropertyAbstract[C]

abstract class ClassAbstract {
  val props: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[String, PropertyAbstract[_ <: A]]
  def get(prop: String) = props.get(prop).get
}

class Class extends ClassAbstract {
  val props = collection.immutable.HashMap(
      "prop1" -> new PropertyA,
      "prop2" -> new PropertyB
  )
}

object Test extends App {
  val the_class = new Class
  val proxied_prop = the_class.get("prop1")
  val direct_prop =  the_class.props.get("prop1").get

  // wont compile (found: B     required: _$1 <: A)
  proxied_prop.revs.add(new B) 
  // wont compile (found: B     required: C with B)
  direct_prop.revs.add(new B)
}
```

The wanted result is that I could add an element of type `B` to prop1, but not an element of type `C`

Comment: For `the_correct_type_prop`, I get `PropertyAbstract[_ >: C with B <: A]`. This is expected if you look at the type of `the_class.props`.

Comment: I also thought that was correct. But is there a way to add Objects of type `B` (and an error when trying to add `C`) to the `revs` array in `PropertyA`? I think the datastructures I use don't allow this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that what you want is essentially a typed map. It's pretty obvious that what you are trying to do simply cannot work. When you call `get`, you receive a `PropertyAbstract[X]` for an unknown `X` (except in that it is a subtype of `A`). How can you then assume it takes `B`s?

The solution is for your `PropertyAbstract` to be *contravariant* but this means that it cannot be a *mutable collection* in any sensible manner (it can be mutable of course, but what you can get out would be an `A`).

```
scala> class A; class B extends A; class C extends A
defined class A
defined class B
defined class C

scala> abstract class PropertyAbstract[-T] { val revs = new java.util.ArrayList[AnyRef] }
defined class PropertyAbstract

scala> class PropertyA extends PropertyAbstract[B]; class PropertyB extends PropertyAbstract[C]
defined class PropertyA
defined class PropertyB

scala> abstract class ClassAbstract {
   | val props: Map[String, PropertyAbstract[_ <: A]]
   | def get(prop: String) = (props get prop).get
   | }
defined class ClassAbstract

scala> class Class extends ClassAbstract { val props = Map("prop1" -> new PropertyA, "prop2" -> new PropertyB) }
defined class Class

scala>  val the_class = new Class
the_class: Class = Class@298508

scala> val proxied_prop = the_class.get("prop1")
proxied_prop: PropertyAbstract[_ <: A] = PropertyA@a269e2

scala> val direct_prop =  the_class.props.get("prop1").get
direct_prop: PropertyAbstract[C with B] = PropertyA@a269e2
```

The following compile:

```
scala> proxied_prop.revs.add(new B)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> direct_prop.revs.add(new B)
res1: Boolean = true
```

But of course you could put anything in there!

Perhaps you should take a look at [Miles Sabin's shapeless](http://www.chuusai.com/2011/12/19/shapeless-preview/) for the sort of stuff you *can* do in terms of heterogeneously-typed collections.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. I'm still quite a newb when it comes to types, variance, generics etc. I now use this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4310959/730277) where the keys of the hashmap contain the type of the value. I also looked up the HList but I have to find out if this also works as a hashmap.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `get` is defined in ClassAbstract and **props is concretely defined in Class and has further type refinement that is not accessible to ClassAbstract**. We need to provide a way for this additional type information to be passed from Class back to ClassAbstract. The following is one method of doing so.

```
abstract class ClassAbstract[P <: PropertyAbstract[_ <: A]] {
  val props: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[String,P]
  def get(prop: String) = props.get(prop)
}

class Class extends ClassAbstract[Property] {
  val props = collection.immutable.HashMap(
      "prop" -> new Property
  )
}
```

This makes the direct get call return something of type Property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not what I want (see the updated the question). What if I have different type of properties in props and all the properties are subtypes of PropertyAbstract?