# Varargs with different type parameters in scala

Tags: scala, types, variadic-functions

I'm new to Scala...

Anyway, I want to do something like:

```
val bar = new Foo("a" -> List[Int](1), "b" -> List[String]("2"), ...)
bar("a") // gives List[Int] containing 1
bar("b") // gives List[String] containing "2"
```

The problem when I do:

```
class Foo(pairs: (String, List[_])*) {
  def apply(name: String): List[_] = pairs.toMap(name)
}
```

`pairs` is gonna be Array[(String, List[Any]) (or something like that) and `apply()` is wrong anyway since `List[_]` is one type instead of "different types". Even if the varargs * returned a tuple I'm still not sure how I'd go about getting `bar("a")` to return a `List[OriginalTypePassedIn]`. So is there actually a way of doing this? Scala seems pretty flexible so it feels like there should be some advanced way of doing this.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate, but pretty similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684023/different-types-in-map-scala

Comment: @Rüdiger Your answer in the link is really cool, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done. Consider this:

```
val key = readStringFromUser();
val value = bar(key);
```

what would be the type of `value`? It would depend on what the user has input. But types are static, they're determined and used at compile time.

So you'll either have to use a fixed number of arguments for which you know their types at compile time, or use a generic vararg and do type casts during runtime.

Answer (score 2):

No.

That's just the nature of static type systems: a method has a fixed return type. It cannot depend on the values of the method's parameters, because the parameters are not known at compile time. Suppose you have `bar`, which is an instance of `Foo`, and you don't know anything about how it was instantiated. You call `bar("a")`. You will get back an instance of the correct type, but since that type isn't determined until runtime, there's no way for a compiler to know it.

Scala does, however, give you a convenient syntax for subtyping `Foo`:

```
object bar extends Foo {
  val a = List[Int](1)
  val b = List[String]("2")
}
```