# How do I leverage Scala's type system to maintain type information for a dynamic set of attributes

Tags: json, mongodb, scala

I've run into a use case where I need to parse a bunch of information from a txt file. The meat of the payload is a bunch of `key:value` pairs, none of which I know at development time.

```
Wombat
Area: "Northern Alberta"
Tank Level (ft): -3.395
Temperature (C): 19.3
Batt Voltage: 13.09
Last Maintained: 2012-01-01
Secured: "Yes"
```

As you can see, there is potential for Strings, Numbers, Dates and Booleans. There is also a use case where the user needs to create rules for certain attributes, things like:

When the **Tank Level** exceeds **n**, please notify *some.user@someplace.com* 
When a **Site** that contains "Alberta" is **Not Secured**, please notify *some.user@someplace.com*

Depending on the type of attribute, the available rule types will differ. I may also need to do some kind of aggregation on the numeric types. Anyway, to make a long story short, I need the type information. So what kind of data structure is best?

Initially I was going to go with distinct tuples.

```
val stringAttributes: Array[(String, String)]
val doubleAttributes: Array[(String, Double)]
val dateAttributes: Array[(String, Date)]
```

Now that seems wrong, or at the very least ugly. Then I though maybe something like:

```
val attributes: Array[(String, Any)]
```

Now I have a pattern match in many of places. Also note I'm using a JSON protocol for the web application and database (MongoDB). It'd be convenient to give the front end something like this:

```
{
    site: "Wombat",
    attributes: [
        { "Area": "Northern Alberta" },
        { "Tank Level (ft)": -3.395 },
        { "Temperature (C)": 19.3 }
    ]
}
```

But in the back end, do I encode the types? Do I parse raw JSON? In the end, I'm looking for the best way to maintain type information for dynamic set of attributes while supporting JSON to both the web client and the database.

Comment: It sounds like you want to JSON end-to-end so why not just represent the data in your server code using lift-json types such as `JObject` and `JField`? Then your main task will be parsing the incoming text files.

Comment: Ultimately, you'll have a hard job doing better than your separate collections for things of each type, since you're unaware of the types until runtime. There are cool things such as shapeless's `HList` which let you build up and operate on heterogenously typed elements, but since most type information is erased at runtime I don't think you can get much benefit from these.

Comment: You need something like a heterogenous map. This question might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684023/different-types-in-map-scala

Answer (score 0):

+1 on @david's comment.

Why not use JSON end-to-end and **derive the type desired for each individual rule**? Then use a single function to transform a JSON value to the correct type (using defaults or `Option` when it doesn't really match).

Then you can use something like this to run the ruleset over all of the parsed objects:

```
for (object <- parseObjects(); rule <- rules) {
  val value = coerce(object, rule.desiredType)
  rule(value)
}
```

Or something similar, such as having the rule itself call the coercion code. It seems like you don't really need the objects to have a type until you're doing rule processing, so why try to?

P.S. 
[Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) may be able to parse the file for you already, although it looks to be a simple format to parse.