# Restriction on Map key/value types, how to make them linked?

Tags: java, scala, types

In Scala code, I have

```
val pendingServices = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, JMap[Class[_ <: Service], Service]]()
```

From the caller side, Java, using looks like

```
Service$.MODULE$.pendingServices().get("key").put(Foo.class, new Foo());
```

Also I am able to get instance of some `Service` class by

```
Service$.MODULE$.pendingServices().get("key").get(Foo.class)
```

or from Scala,

```
Service.pendingServices.get("key").get(classOf[Foo])
```

The problem: it is possible to put unrelated `Service`es in the map, like

```
Service$.MODULE$.pendingServices().get("key").put(Bar.class, new Foo());
```

if `Foo` and `Bar` both extends `Service`. So, how can I restrict `Class[_ <: Service` and `Service` from the definition to share same `Service` ?

I want to demonstrate my coworkers some cases when Scala's type system really helps. Tried with type lambdas, but my type-fu is not strong enought.

Comment: This question might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684023/different-types-in-map-scala/17686005#17686005

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use such construction in the scala code

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{HashMap ⇒ MHMap,  SynchronizedMap}
import scala.reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}

class Service

case class Foo() extends Service
case class Bar() extends Service

object Service {
  object pendingServices {
    private val backing = (new MHMap[String, Map[Class[_], Service]] with SynchronizedMap)
        .withDefaultValue(Map.empty)

    def update[T <: Service : ClassTag](name: String, service: T): Unit =
      backing(name) += classTag[T].runtimeClass → service

    def apply[T <: Service : ClassTag](name: String): T =
      backing(name)(classTag[T].runtimeClass).asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}
```

in scala you could use it as

```
val foo = new Foo
val bar = new Bar

pendingServices("baz") = foo
pendingServices("baz") = bar

println(pendingServices[Foo]("baz")) // Foo()
println(pendingServices[Bar]("baz")) // Bar()
```

in java equivalent would be

```
final Foo foo = new Foo();
final Bar bar = new Bar();
Service.pendingServices$.MODULE$.update("baz", foo, ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Foo.class));
Service.pendingServices$.MODULE$.update("baz", bar, ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Bar.class));

System.out.println(Service.pendingServices$.MODULE$.<Foo>apply("baz", ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Foo.class))); // Foo()
System.out.println(Service.pendingServices$.MODULE$.<Bar>apply("baz", ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Bar.class))); // Bar()
```

It still does not restrict anything outside scala, but can work as demo

Comment: Nice, ClassTag can be really useful.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to wrap the map into some helper class. You could use something like (Java syntax):

```
public class ServiceRepository {

    private Map<Class<?>, Object> repo = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> void put(Class<T> clazz, T service) {
         repo.put(clazz, service);
    }

    public <T> T get(Class<T> clazz) {
        return (T) repo.get(clazz);
    }

}
```

Comment: That's a possible solution, but it's rather dirty. I'd like to use some Scala's type systems hack, if possible.