# Cast values from Any using ClassManifest in Scala

Tags: scala, manifest, casting, type-erasure

I've got a `List[Any]` of values and a list of corresponding `ClassManifest[_]`s, storing values' original types. How do i cast some value from list back to it's original type?

`def cast[T](x: Any, mf: ClassManifest[T]): T = x.asInstanceOf[T]` doesn't work.

Thank You for your answers.

Comment: Your question is quite similra to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can't ever possibly work, as the return type of `cast` will always be taken as the highest common supertype of whatever `T` is restricted to.  There's no way it can be made any more specific at compile time.

If you're trying to build a strongly-typed collection of disparate types, then what you really want is an HList:

http://jnordenberg.blogspot.com/2008/09/hlist-in-scala-revisited-or-scala.html

Comment: Thx, it looks interesting, but am i correct that for now HList is limited by 10 elements?

Comment: @fehu: Why would you think that?  One of the motivations for an HList is that it can hold an arbitrary number of elements, exceeding the 22-element limit of a Tuple.

Answer (score 0):

The way to use a `Class` instance in Java/Scala to cast an object is to use the `Class.cast` method. So you may think that you could do:

```
mf.erasure.cast(x) //T
```

But this will not work, because `mf.erasure` is a `Class[_]` (or a `Class<?>` in Java), so the cast is meaningless (i.e. offers no extra information). This is (of course) one of the drawbacks in using non-reified generics.