# Retrieve type parameter in pattern matching in scala

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching

I already found that it is possible to [bind the type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4531081/1287856) in a pattern matching

Why does not that work in that case ?

```
trait T

case class S[A](a: A) extends T

def pr(t1: T, t2: T) = (t1, t2) match {
  case (S(a): S[ta], S(b): S[tb]) => println(a); println(b)
}
                         ^
error: '=>' expected but ':' found.
```

For information, this works:

```
def pr(t1: T, t2: T) = (t1, t2) match {
  case (s1: S[a], s2: S[b]) => println(s1.a); println(s2.a)
}
```

And this as well:

```
def pr(t1: T, t2: T) = (t1, t2) match {
  case (S(a), S(b)) => println(a); println(b)
}
```

I need to recover the type to define other functions whose type cannot be inferred because in the context of [eta-expansion](http://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/functional-scala-turning-methods-into-functions/).

**UPDATE**

As mentionned in the comments, I need the types just for correct type checking, not anything else.

For example:

```
trait T
case class S[A](a: A, w: A => Int) extends T
def makeTwo(t1: T, t2: T) = (t1, t2) match {
  case (S(a1, w1), S(a2, w2)) =>
    val wNew = { (a, b) => w1(a) + w2(b) }
    S((a, b), wNew)
}

error: missing parameter type
  val wNew = { (a, b) => w1(a) + w2(b) }
                ^
```

Comment: You can't retrieve type parameter info because it doesn't exist at runtime - see type erasure

Comment: @LuigiPlinge, type erasure here does not really matter. The author does not need to obtain real type, he needs to bind a type in order for the code to pass the type checking. I also had to do something like this when I was writing generic [de]serialization library, however, I somehow had avoided this problem.

Comment: Try putting a type annotation in for the `makeTwo` method and you'll see the problem. A `T` in this scheme can be absolutely anything

Comment: In this case, T is not a type variable, it is really a trait. Should I make it sealed ?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from Scala syntax rules:

```
varid ::= lower idrest

idrest ::= {letter | digit} [‘_’ op]

op ::= opchar {opchar}

opchar ::= “all other characters in \u0020-007F and Unicode
            categories Sm, So except parentheses ([]) and periods”

// 'a' and 'a_-' is valid, 'a(' is not.
```

Rule for Typed Pattern match says:

```
Pattern1 ::= varid ‘:’ TypePat
           | ‘_’   ‘:’ TypePat
```

So

```
def pr(list: Any) = list match {

   case a :String => // works
   case a_- :String => // works a_- is valid instance of 'varid'
   case a() :String => // does not work.
   case a(b) :List[Int] // does not work either!
}
```

Hence:

```
case S(a): S[ta]  is not valid syntax for pattern match.
```

However following is valid

```
case (s1 :S[a], s2: S[b])
```

according to Tuple Pattern matching rule:

```
SimplePattern ::= ‘(’ [Patterns] ‘)’
Patterns ::= Pattern {‘,’ Patterns}
```

Apart from the two possible options that you have listed, you may also use:

```
 case tup: (S[_], S[_]) =>
```

Following seems to work:

```
trait T

case class S[A](a: A, w: A => Int) extends T

def makeTwo(t1: T, t2: T) = (t1, t2) match {
  case (S(a1, w1), S(a2, w2)) =>
      val wNew = {  tup:(Any, Any) => w1(tup._1) + w2(tup._2) }
      S((a1, a2), wNew)
}

def someString (s: String) = { s.length }

val twoS = makeTwo(S("Hello", someString), S("World!", someString))
println(twoS.w(twoS.a))  // gives 11
```

Comment: "<console>:11: warning: non-variable type argument S[ta] in type pattern (S[ta],
S[tb]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
         case tup: (S[ta], S[tb]) =>"

And when I continue:

<console>:12: error: missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: ?
           val wNew = {case (a: ta, b: tb) => tup._1.w(a) + tup._2.w(b) }

Comment: @MikaëlMayer see the updated version, with wNew defined as taking param of (Any, Any)

Answer (score 0):

In at least some circumstances you can get what you want.

If you add a context bound (syntactic sugar for an implicit parameters) of the type `ClassTag` to the type parameter you want enforced by the compiler, it will have what it needs to do that.

E.g., I have a generic bit of Akka plumbing I used to buffer messages between producers and consumers which I want to be type-safe.

The class is defined like this:

```
class   TimedBatchQueue[T : ClassTag](batchLimit:   Int,
                                      MaxQueueTime: FiniteDuration,
                                      receiver:     ActorRef)
extends Actor
```

The receive function includes a case for the incomming messages it is to buffer:

```
  def receive = {
    ...
    case mesg: T => /* Enqueue the message */
    case mesg    => /* Bounce the unacceptable message back to the sender encapsulated in a reject message */
  }
```