# Selecting a subset of types from a generic collection

Tags: generics, scala, collections, type-erasure

Okay guys, I'm starting to get some scala now, but every now and then the trickier concepts get me. Let me introduce you to the fruit world:

```
class Fruit
class Pear extends Fruit
class Apple extends Fruit
class GrannySmith extends Apple
```

Now what if I want a new generic collection that allows me to pick subsets of Fruits out of the generic collection. Naive implementation:

```
class MyArray[T](var a:Array[T]) {
  def select[U <: T] = 
    a.filter(_ match {
      case u:U => true
      case _   => false
    })
}
```

This does not work however.

```
scala> var ma = new MyArray(
                        Array(
                          new Apple, 
                          new Fruit, 
                          new Pear, 
                          new GrannySmith, 
                          new Apple, 
                          new Fruit
                        ))


scala> ma.select[Apple]
res1: Array[Fruit] = Array(Apple@4d815146, Fruit@64fef26a, Pear@1ddd40f3, GrannySmith@28d320d6, Apple@3d10d68a, Fruit@1c751d58)
```

The console warned about unchecked errors, rerunning with -unchecked gave this while defining MyArray:

```
<console>:8: warning: abstract type U in type pattern U is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
             case u:U => true
```

So my understanding of type erasure is very vague. I know that it is somehow related to the limited dynamic types in the jvm, and that you can sometimes get around it using Manifests as Daniel is talking about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-parameter). What I particularly don't understand is how this works in this example, and how one could get around it.

I'm thankful for any help!

Answer (score 3):

How about this? You even get the right return type.

```
ma.a.collect { case a: Apple => a }
```

Comment: ...you could say that I accidentally posted before I had added my actual question =)