# Scala: Selecting a subset of types from a generic collection without std collections. (collect)

Tags: generics, scala, collections, type-erasure

Following my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067332/selecting-a-subset-of-types-from-a-generic-collection) came a quick and great answer, however it turned out my example didn't match my actual production code well enough. In summary I'm in need of a new implementation of the collect method.

The second fruit world (with some pretty funky fruit trees):

```
class Fruit {
    var seeds:Array[Fruit] = Array()
    def naiveCollect[F <: Fruit]:Array[Fruit] = this match {
        case f:F => Array(this)
        case _ => seeds.map(_.select[F]).flatten.toArray
    }
}

class Apple extends Fruit
class Pear extends Fruit
class GrannySmith extends Apple
```

Does not work because of type erasure:

```
var tree = new Fruit { seeds = Array(
                new Apple,
                new Pear,
                new GrannySmith,
                new Pear { seeds = Array(
                    new Apple,
                    new Pear)},
                new Apple)}

scala> tree.naiveCollect[Apple]
res1: Array[Fruit] = Array($anon$2@5a4b99fa)

// wanted output: Apple, GrannySmith, Apple, Apple
```

**EDIT, SOLUTION1:**

Turns out i managed to produce something which works by using the PartialFunction as in the std lib.

```
class Fruit {
    ...
    def clumsyCollect[F](pf:PartialFunction[Fruit, F]):Seq[F] = 
        if (pf.isDefinedAt(this))
            List(pf(this))
        else
            seeds.flatMap(_.selectPartial[F](pf))
}
```

Use case:

```
tree.clumsyCollect { case a:Apple => a }
```

Any alternatives or tips on cleaning this up would still be great though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is `scala.reflect.ClassManifest`

```
class Fruit {
    var seeds:Array[Fruit] = Array()
    def select[F <: Fruit](implicit cm: ClassManifest[F]): Array[F] = 
      if (cm.erasure.isInstance(this))        
        Array(this.asInstanceOf[F])
      else 
        seeds.flatMap(_.select[F])
}
```

With every call of `select` an implicit parameter containing actual class information will be passed. You can now make class checks at runtime, and also you can return `Array` of more specific type.

This produces desired result:

```
scala> tree.select[Apple]
res12: Array[Apple] = Array(Apple@10fa4d, GrannySmith@a10ca8, Apple@14611ec, Apple@142b533)
```

Alternatively, you can use *context bound* syntax:

```
def select[F <: Fruit : ClassManifest]: Array[F] = 
  if (classManifest[F].erasure.isInstance(this))        
...
```

Comment: This is just what I was getting at, thanks! Swinging around those ClassManifests is a little clumsy (not your code, but in general), but I suppose it's a pretty advanced functionality after all.

Answer (score 1):

Manifests can be used to work around erasure. Since we're only interested in the manifest's erasure, we use a ClassManifest here because it's more lightweight.

The following is simple and works but the return type of select is Array[Fruit], not Array[F].

```
  class Fruit {
      var seeds: Array[Fruit] = Array()
      def select[F <: Fruit](implicit m: ClassManifest[F]): Array[Fruit] =
        seeds.filter(s => m.erasure.isInstance(s)) 
  }
```

The following provides a return type of Array[F] but is a little more involved.

```
  class Fruit {
      var seeds: Array[Fruit] = Array()
      def select[F <: Fruit](implicit m: ClassManifest[F]): Array[F] = {
        seeds.foldLeft(Array.newBuilder[F]) { (b, s) =>
          if(m.erasure.isInstance(s)) b += s.asInstanceOf[F] else b
        }.result
      }
  }
```

Edit: I just noticed that I didn't answer what the op asked. I will leave my answer anyway, maybe it's useful to someone.