# Scala : Generic abstract type ignored for isInstanceOf

Tags: generics, scala

Can someone explain why the output of this code is `true true`, instead of `true false`.

I would also like to know how I could achieve a output that is `true false` using `def apply(in:Any)`. I've tried parameterised types too, and still i get `true true` instead of `true false`.

```
 object TestClass extends App {

  val xTrue = TypeXObject(TypeX("s"))
  val xFalse = TypeXObject(TypeY(1))
 }

 case class TypeX(string:String)

 case class TypeY(int:Int)

 object TypeXObject extends HasAbstractType{override type T = TypeX}

 object TypeYObject extends HasAbstractType{override type T = TypeY}

 abstract class HasAbstractType {
   type T
   def apply(in:Any):Any = {
     println(in.isInstanceOf[T])
     in
   }
 }
```

Answer:

issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5042 - With article and the attached article i found that I can get the `true false` with `manifest[T1].erasure.isInstance(t1)` and `manifest[T1].erasure.isInstance(t2)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I compile your code I get the following compiler message:

```
[warn] there were 1 unchecked warnings; re-run with -unchecked for details
[warn] one warning found
```

To pass `-unchecked` to the compiler, I create a build.sbt containing:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecated") // (I threw in deprecated for good measure)
```

Then when I compile, I get this enlightening warning:

```
[warn] /home/lwickland/f/f.scala:18: abstract type HasAbstractType.this.T in type HasAbstractType.this.T is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
[warn]     println(in.isInstanceOf[T])
```

And at that point, I have to refer you to an [excellent explanation of type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete) and how to get around it.

Comment: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5042 - Your article and this article i found that I can get the `true false` with `manifest[T1].erasure.isInstance(t1)` and `manifest[T1].erasure.isInstance(t2)`. Thanks for the help