# How to distinguish between objects with different abstract type fields?

Tags: scala, types

Assume, we have an abstract class with an abstract type field:

```
abstract class A {type T}
```

Now let's assume, we have a method, which returns objects of type `A`, but the type field `T` may differ. How can we distinguish between these objects ?

We can try a pattern match:

```
object Test {
  def tryToDistinguish(a: A) = 
    a match {
      case b: A {type T = String} => println("String type")
      case b: A {type T = Int} => println("Int type")
      case b: A => println("Other type")
  }
}
```

But the compiler will complain:

```
$>scalac -unchecked Test.scala
Test.scala:8: warning: refinement example.test.A{type T = String} in type patter
n example.test.A{type T = String} is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure

      case b: A {type T = String} => println("String type")
          ^
Test.scala:9: warning: refinement example.test.A{type T = Int} in type pattern e
xample.test.A{type T = Int} is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
          case b: A {type T = Int} => println("Int type")
              ^
two warnings found
```

It seems the type of the type field will be removed by erasure (**side question:** Because type fields are translated to parameter types in Java ?)

Therefore, this will not work:

```
scala> Test.tryToDistinguish(new A {type T = Int})
String type
```

**Alternative :** We can alternativley create an enumeration and put an additional field in the class `A` in order to distinguish the objects. But this smells, because it would mean, that we re-implement the type system.

**Question :** Is there a way to differ between the types of the objects with the help of the type field ? And if not, what will be a good workaround ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `<%<` which tells you in compile-time if two types are compatible.

```
scala> class A { type T }
defined class A

scala> implicitly[A { type T=String } <%< A { type T=Int } ]
<console>:9: error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: <%<[A{type T = String},A{type T = Int}]
              implicitly[A { type T=String } <%< A { type T=Int } ]
                        ^

scala> implicitly[A { type T=String } <%< A { type T=String } ]
res1: <%<[A{type T = String},A{type T = String}] = <function1>

scala> implicitly[A { type T=String } <%< A ]
res3: <%<[A{type T = String},A] = <function1>
```

Comment: Thank you. How is the `<%<` be called ? I would like to read more about it in the Scala documentation.

Comment: Same here, could you please explain what the intuitive semantics of ``<%<`` and ``implicitly`` are?

Comment: The docs http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef$$$less$colon$less

Comment: `implicitly` is `def implicitly[T](implicit e: T) = e` so it only "grabs" a implicit of type T in the scope.

Answer (score 2):

As you guessed, abstract type members are a compile time information that will be erased during type erasure. Here is a work around that uses `implicit` parameters. The dispatch is static.

```
scala> class A {
     |   type T
     | }
defined class A

scala> implicit def distString(a: A { type T = String }) = "String"
distString: (a: A{type T = String})java.lang.String

scala> implicit def distInt(a: A { type T = Int }) = "Int"
distInt: (a: A{type T = Int})java.lang.String

scala> implicit def distOther[O](a: A { type T = O }) = "Other"
distOther: [O](a: A{type T = O})java.lang.String

scala> def distinguish(a: A)(implicit ev: A { type T = a.T } => String) = ev(a)
distinguish: (a: A)(implicit ev: A{type T = a.T} => String)String

scala> distinguish(new A { type T = String })
res2: String = String

scala> distinguish(new A { type T = Int })
res3: String = Int

scala> distinguish(new A { type T = Float })
res4: String = Other
```

Another way:

```
scala> def dist(a: A)(implicit s: a.T =:= String = null, i: a.T =:= Int = null) =
     |   if (s != null) "String" else if (i != null) "Int" else "Other"
dist: (a: A)(implicit s: =:=[a.T,String], implicit i: =:=[a.T,Int])String

scala> dist(new A { type T = String })
res5: String = String

scala> dist(new A { type T = Int })
res6: String = Int

scala> dist(new A { type T = Float })
res7: String = Other
```

---

**Edit:**

If the above solutions do not satisfy you, and you want to reify and introspect this type information at runtime after all, you can do that as well, using something called `Manifest`s.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

abstract class A {
  type T
  def man: Manifest[T]
}

object A {
  def apply[X](implicit m: Manifest[X]) = new A { type T = X; def man = m }
}


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class A
defined module A

scala> def disti(a: A): String = a match {
     |   case _ if a.man <:< manifest[String] => "String"
     |   case _ if a.man <:< manifest[Int] => "Int"
     |   case _ => "Other"
     | }
disti: (a: A)String

scala> disti(A.apply[String])
res14: String = String

scala> disti(A.apply[Int])
res15: String = Int

scala> disti(A.apply[Float])
res16: String = Other
```

Answer (score 1):

> side question: Because type fields are translated to parameter types
>   in Java ?

There are no type parameters in bytecode, so type fields could not possibly be translated into them. Type fields only exist during compilation.

> Alternative : We can alternativley create an enumeration and put an
>   additional field in the class A in order to distinguish the objects.
>   But this smells, because it would mean, that we re-implement the type
>   system.

There's only one kind of type question you can make at run time: what class is this? Scala 2.10 gives a bit more information, but it still boils down to that question.

If you actually subclass `A`, you can get that information through reflection (on 2.10). Otherwise, I don't think so -- I've tested on REPL, and there it doesn't work, but things compiled to class files have more information on them.

Any other question has to be made about values.

> Question : Is there a way to differ between the types of the objects
>   with the help of the type field ? And if not, what will be a good
>   workaround ?

No, unless Scala 2.10, reflection, and subclasses. Good workaround? Use values. The usual way to handle it is not enumeration, though, but `Manifest`, which can be generated implicitly.

Look up [questions about how to get around type erasure in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete).

Comment: Well sure type fields must be somehow represented in compiled class files? Otherwise how would I refer them when they appear in a compiled library? There must be some information that carries the name and the bounds, no?

Comment: @Sciss There is. If you use `javap -s` on a class file generate by Scala, you'll see a constant ScalaSig followed by a constant with a binary package representation of the type. What is missing is the ability to decode it. As to whether an anonymous class would have that information, that I have no idea.