# Scala: Filtering collection based on type parameter

Tags: scala, collections, type-erasure

What is the best way to filter a collection of objects based on the type parameters of those objects, assuming that I have control over both classes and that I need covariant filtering?

Here is some code that doesn't work properly:

```
trait Foo
case class Foo1() extends Foo
trait ReadableFoo extends Foo {def field: Int}
case class Foo2(field: Int, flag: Boolean) extends ReadableFoo
case class Foo3(field: Int, name: String) extends ReadableFoo

case class Bar[+F <: Foo](foo: F)

val seq = Seq(
  Bar[Foo1](Foo1()),
  Bar[Foo2](Foo2(1,true)), 
  Bar[Foo3](Foo3(1,"Fooz"))
)

// Should keep one
val first = seq collect {case x: Bar[Foo2] => x}

// Should keep two
val both = seq collect {case x: Bar[ReadableFoo] => x}
```

Now, I know that is it because the `case x: Bar[Foo1]` gets converted via type erasure to `case x: Bar[_]` after compilation. I have been unable to use Manifests to solve this problem. Is there some way to add a member type (i.e. `memberType = F`) to `Bar` that I can just switch on like `case x if (x.memberType <:< ReadableFoo) => x`?

**Update**

0__ quickly found a good solution to the original problem. A slight modification is when the case class field is itself a collection:

```
case class Bar[+F <: Foo](foo: Seq[F])

val seq = Seq(
  Bar[Foo1](Seq(Foo1())),
  Bar[Foo2](Seq(Foo2(1,true))),
  Bar[ReadableFoo](Seq(Foo2(1,true), Foo3(1,"Fooz")))
)

// Should keep one
val first = seq collect {case x: Bar[Foo2] => x}

// Should keep two
val both = seq collect {case x: Bar[ReadableFoo] => x}
```

I'm not sure this is possible since the `Seq` could be empty and, therefore, have no elements to test.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310547/how-to-distinguish-between-objects-with-different-abstract-type-fields/11311312#11311312) might help.

Comment: @missingfaktor Yes, I suppose printing all the type parameters to strings and then doing my own ad-hoc inheritance testing using a tree of strings would be one way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't aware of the type checking at the extractor trick so my initial solution to your fist problem would've been a little different. I would've provided an extractor for `ReadableFoo`

```
object ReadableFoo { def unapply(x: ReadableFoo) = Some(x.field) }
```

Then you could do

```
val first = seq collect { case x @ Bar(Foo2(_,_)) => x }
val both  = seq collect { case x @ Bar(ReadableFoo(_)) => x }
```

But for your updated code, I think you'd need to drag along a manifest.

```
case class Bar[+F <: Foo : Manifest](foo: Seq[F]) { 
    def manifest = implicitly[Manifest[_ <: F]] 
}
```

Since Bar is covariant and Manifest is invariant we can't simply promise to return a Manifest[F] but a Manifest of some subtype of F. (I guess this was your problem when trying to use manifests?)
After that you can do

```
val first = seq collect {case x if x.manifest <:< manifest[Foo2] => x}
val both = seq collect {case x if x.manifest <:< manifest[ReadableFoo] => x}
```

Still, using manifests always feels a little hacky. I'd see if I can use a different approach and rely on type matching and reification as little as possible.

Comment: That seems to work perfectly (after I drop an `asInstanceOf` on `x`, per Sciss's suggestion). Is there a catch, because it seems that the Scala compiler would inject those `def manifest` and `if` statements automatically if it was just this easy?

Comment: Well it adds some overhead I suppose. The compiler injects only the manifests themselves on demand but always for arrays since they actually need to map to Java arrays. For everything else, they are really not that frequently wanted and less frequently needed. Simply using case classes/extractors and matching on values is good enough most of the time.

Answer (score 8):

You can combine extractor with type check:

```
val first = seq collect { case x @ Bar(_: Foo2)        => x }
val both  = seq collect { case x @ Bar(_: ReadableFoo) => x }
```

But the return type will still be `List[Bar[Foo]]` ... so if you need that, with this approach you would need to cast or re-construct the `Bar` object (`case Bar(f: Foo2) => Bar(f)`).

---

With a heterogeneous `Seq` I guess you are looking for `collect` on the `Seq` itself?

```
case class Bar(seq: Seq[Foo])

def onlyFoo2(b: Bar) = Bar(b.seq.collect { case f: Foo2 => f })

onlyFoo2(Bar(Seq(Foo1(), Foo2(1, true))))
```

Comment: Can this be chained, like if `Bar` had a `foo: Seq[F]` rather than just `foo: F`? I can edit the question if that would improve clarity.

Comment: As long as you have extractors, yes. It would be `case Bar(Seq(f: Foo2) => Bar(Seq(f))` -- again if you need the return type to be `Bar[Seq[Foo2]]` you need to either cast or rebuild the object

Comment: Wouldn't that `Seq(f: Foo2)` only match a sequence with a single element?

Comment: Are you planning to have different `Foo` subtypes within a `Seq`, or are all of the the same, e.g. `Seq[Foo2]`?

Comment: They are going to be different subtypes. It could be a `Seq` of `Foo2` and `Foo3` so that `Bar` and `Seq` will be parameterized with `ReadableFoo`.