# Pattern matching Type as a parameter for functions, methods, etc

Tags: scala

I was making good progress with Scala's pattern matching (amazing btw) until I tried to make a dynamic function to match "Instance of" and in the future as part of an object maybe save that [type] for later. Now I understand how to use pattern class matching

case X:Int => ....

but why does this (below) seem to work for anything passed to it?? Further more I can't really seem to work with [TYPE] , is it an object? I can't print it or val = , etc.. I thought about trying to work with the java.Class associated but that doesn't seem correct. Any advise is appreciated, thank you!

```
class Parent

class Child extends Parent

object TestTypes {

  def testRelate[TYPE](o:Any) = {

     o match {
       case o:TYPE => println(" o is a matching type")
       case _  => println(" o fails")
     }

     // val save = [TYPE]  .. why can't I do this?
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val p = new Parent
    val c = new Child
    testRelate[Int](c)   // why does this Match???
    testRelate[Parent](c)   // 

  }

}
```

--- Update
so just to clarify (and thank you for the answers) but how then can someone accomplish pattern matching of classtype dynamically during runtime? It seems scala has a static type matching (that beings to breakdown in the example above), but is instanceOf( ) my choice of dynamic checking?

Comment: Tip: when the compiler tells you that something isn't right, pay attention to it.

Comment: See the edit part of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310547/how-to-distinguish-between-objects-with-different-abstract-type-fields/11311312#11311312). (This is the third time I am posting this this week.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type parameters are erased at run time, so `TYPE` is effectively equivalent to `Object`, which means anything.

Also type parameters are types, not values, so you can't assign it to a variable. At most, you could do this:

```
type save = TYPE
```

However, that is erased too, so it isn't saving anything.

Comment: Thank you, would you happen to know how this might working using java.class .. or does Scala have it's own "class" object type?

Comment: @LaloInDublin This happens at compile time, so class files aren't much of a concern. However, Scala stores type information as constants on class files, to allow for separate compilation. You can look at it with `javap`, though it's binary-encoded and, thus, illegible.

Answer (score 1):

For more powerful runtime type checking you may want to look at `scala.reflect.Manifest[T]`.  It wraps a `java.lang.Class[T]` and adds some nice variance checking operators.

Here is a usage example: [The EnMAS POMDP State Class](https://github.com/ConnorDoyle/EnMAS/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/enmas/pomdp/State.scala)