# How to create a TypeTag manually?

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

I'm interested in creating a TypeTag manually (since 2.10M5):

```
object X {
  import reflect.runtime.universe._
  def tt[A : TypeTag](a: A) = typeTag[A] // how to do this manually?
  val t = tt(List("")(_))
}
```

`scalac -Xprint:typer <file>.scala` results in

```
package <empty> {
  object X extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>(): X.type = {
      X.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    import scala.reflect.runtime.`package`.universe._;
    def tt[A >: Nothing <: Any](a: A)(implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A]): reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A] = scala.reflect.runtime.`package`.universe.typeTag[A](evidence$1);
    private[this] val t: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Int => String] = X.this.tt[Int => String](((x$1: Int) => immutable.this.List.apply[String]("").apply(x$1)))({
      val $u: reflect.runtime.universe.type = scala.this.reflect.runtime.`package`.universe;
      val $m: $u.Mirror = scala.this.reflect.runtime.`package`.universe.runtimeMirror(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
      $u.TypeTag.apply[Int => String]($m, {
        final class $typecreator1 extends TypeCreator {
          def <init>(): $typecreator1 = {
            $typecreator1.super.<init>();
            ()
          };
          def apply[U >: Nothing <: scala.reflect.base.Universe with Singleton]($m$untyped: scala.reflect.base.MirrorOf[U]): U#Type = {
            val $u: U = $m$untyped.universe;
            val $m: $u.Mirror = $m$untyped.asInstanceOf[$u.Mirror];
            $u.TypeRef.apply($u.ThisType.apply($m.staticModule("scala").asModuleSymbol.moduleClass), $m.staticClass("scala.Function1"), scala.collection.immutable.List.apply[$u.Type]($m.staticClass("scala.Int").asTypeSymbol.asTypeConstructor, $m.staticClass("java.lang.String").asTypeSymbol.asTypeConstructor))
          }
        };
        new $typecreator1()
      })
    });
    <stable> <accessor> def t: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Int => String] = X.this.t
  }
}
```

It seems to be completely compiler magic because the types are hardcoded. Nevertheless is there a way to do this manually?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In M3 you could create a type tag in a very simple way, e.g.: `TypeTag[Int](TypeRef(<scala package>, <symbol of scala.Int>, Nil))`. It basically meant that once a type tag is created, it is forever bound to a certain classloader (namely the one that was used to load a symbol of scala.Int in the example above).

Back then it was fine, because we considered that we could have a one-size-fits-all mirror that accomodates all classloaders. That was convenient, because you could just write `implicitly[TypeTag[T]]` and the compiler would use that global mirror to instantiate a Type you requested.

Unfortunately later, based on feedback, we realized that this isn't going to work, and that we need multiple mirrors - each having its own classloader.

And then it became apparent that type tags need to be flexible, because once you write that `implicitly[TypeTag[T]]` the compiler doesn't have enough information what classloader you want to use. Basically there were two alternatives: 1) make type tags path-dependent on mirrors (so that one would be forced to explicitly provide a mirror every time a type tag is requested from the compiler), 2) transform type tags into type factories, capable of instantiating themselves in any mirror. Long story short, the first option didn't work, so we are where we are.

So currently type tags need to be created in quite a roundabout way, as outlined in https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/reflect/base/TypeTags.scala#L143. You call a factory method defined in the companion `TypeTag` and provide two arguments: 1) a default mirror, where the type tag will be instantiated, 2) a type factory that can instantiate a type tag in arbitrary mirror. This is basically what the compiler did in the printout you've attached above.

Why I called this roundabout? Because to provide a type factory you need to manually subclass the `scala.reflect.base.TypeFactory` class. That's an unfortunate limitation of Scala type system on the border between function and dependently-typed methods.

Comment: I see, Scala Reflection is much more complicated than I currently can think of. I still have to spent a lot of time until getting what is going on there...

Comment: Could you elaborate on your use case? Constructing type tags (and, consequently, Scala types) on the fly, especially from Java, looks really hardcore. Maybe class tags (that carry just a Java class, not a Scala type) would suffice?

Comment: I do not have a use case ;) I wanted to know how things work and how to use it/work with it for later use...

Comment: The general idea is still the same, but currently, you can do this (in macros) via the following code
https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/3808916f70c34e2e6ecfac1d50ff2cc0bf489834/src/compiler/scala/reflect/macros/contexts/Aliases.scala#L26
That method is even part of the macro API (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.2/scala-reflect/#scala.reflect.macros.Aliases).

Comment: Use-case I heard of: given typetags for F[A] and B, create a typetag for F[B]. (The method taking TypeTag[B] cannot take TypeTag[F[B]] because that would be a invariant usage of F, but F is a covariant type parameter of the containing class.)

Comment: Yes, you can do this in macros, because there's only one mirror in the macro world. In runtime reflection we purposefully don't expose the same factory method, because that would be unreliable.

Comment: The github link is broken.

Comment: I see that API is changed - so you can pass your own implementation of TypeCreator instead of TypeFactory. like here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27889140/1809978

Comment: Here's my use case. I need to call a Java class after overriding a method. I can only do it at run time, what I do using the code found here ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544446/how-do-you-dynamically-compile-and-load-external-java-classes ). The java code of the overridden method needs to interact with the rest of my Scala code, what it does through reflection. Some methods are generic and needs TypeTags.

Answer (score 10):

Based on [Get TypeTag[A] from Class[A]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970209/get-typetaga-from-classa/22972751#22972751):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def typeToTypeTag[T](
  tpe: Type,
  mirror: reflect.api.Mirror[reflect.runtime.universe.type]
): TypeTag[T] = {
  TypeTag(mirror, new reflect.api.TypeCreator {
    def apply[U <: reflect.api.Universe with Singleton](m: reflect.api.Mirror[U]) = {
      assert(m eq mirror, s"TypeTag[$tpe] defined in $mirror cannot be migrated to $m.")
      tpe.asInstanceOf[U#Type]
    }
  })
}
```

For example this can be used to get the `TypeTag` for a part of another `TypeTag`:

```
def inside[A, B](tag: TypeTag[(A, B)]): (TypeTag[A], TypeTag[B]) = {
  val tpes = tag.tpe.asInstanceOf[TypeRefApi].args
  val tagA = typeToTypeTag[A](tpes(0), tag.mirror)
  val tagB = typeToTypeTag[B](tpes(1), tag.mirror)
  return (tagA, tagB)
}
```

This works in Scala 2.10.2:

```
scala> inside(typeTag[(Int, Double)])
res0: (reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Int], reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Double]) = (TypeTag[Int],TypeTag[Double])
```

The limitation of being tied to a particular `Mirror` is likely not a problem as long as you don't have multiple `ClassLoader`s.

Comment: This method loses the ability for the tag to be serialized: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror

Comment: I'm on Scala 2.10, so I never saw serializable TypeTags. Must be awesome! :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473734/in-scala-2-12-why-none-of-the-typetag-created-in-runtime-is-serializable/

Answer (score 8):

Currently, there are three ways to create a `TypeTag` **that supports generics** manually. The first two depends on the `scala-compiler`, and with them you get type checking just like in compile time, *as it is an actual code compilation*:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()

def createTypeTag(tp: String): TypeTag[_] = {
  val ttree = toolbox.parse(s"scala.reflect.runtime.universe.typeTag[$tp]")
  toolbox.eval(ttree).asInstanceOf[TypeTag[_]]
}
```

If you need a serializable `TypeTag` and performance isn't your main concern, the first method is the most succinct. OTOH, if your use case needs to be very performant, beware that on-the-fly compilation might take a couple of seconds to finish.

The second method performs a little better:

```
def createTypeTag(tp: String): TypeTag[_] = {
  val ttagCall = s"scala.reflect.runtime.universe.typeTag[$tp]"
  val tpe = toolbox.typecheck(toolbox.parse(ttagCall), toolbox.TYPEmode).tpe.resultType.typeArgs.head

  TypeTag(currentMirror, new reflect.api.TypeCreator {
    def apply[U <: reflect.api.Universe with Singleton](m: reflect.api.Mirror[U]) = {
      assert(m eq mirror, s"TypeTag[$tpe] defined in $mirror cannot be migrated to $m.")
      tpe.asInstanceOf[U#Type]
    }
  }
}
```

This second mode creates a typed tree and fetches the concrete types marked in the `TypeTag`, i.e., if your target is a `List[String]`, it will be translated to `scala.collection.immutable.List[String]`, since `scala.List` is only a type alias. That's actually the behavior expected from `typeTag[List[String]]`.

The last method is to create a `Type` manually and use it to create the `TypeTag`. This method is error-prone, there is limited type checking, and it uses internal API. This is, however, the fastest way to manually obtain a `TypeTag`.

```
def createTypeTag(tp: String): TypeTag[_] = {
  val typs = // ... manipulate the string to extract type and parameters
  val typSym = currentMirror.staticClass(typs[0])
  val paramSym = currentMirror.staticClass(typs[1])

  val tpe = universe.internal.typeRef(NoPrefix, typSym, List(paramSym.selfType))

  val ttag = TypeTag(currentMirror, new TypeCreator {
    override def apply[U <: Universe with Singleton](m: Mirror[U]): U#Type = {
      assert(m == currentMirror, s"TypeTag[$tpe] defined in $currentMirror cannot be migrated to $m.")
      tpe.asInstanceOf[U#Type]
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: This answer is gold. Thank you.

Comment: Just one thing: the TypeTag created using the first method is serializable but not deserializable, so it is still useless: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: __wrapper$1$2044369228ff48bb85c06775c7f0d775.__wrapper$1$2044369228ff48bb85c06775c7f0d775$$typecreator1$1

Comment: @tribbloid It's both serializable and deserializable. Just `TypeCreator` must be serialized (deserialized and loaded) manually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473734/in-scala-2-12-why-none-of-the-typetag-created-in-runtime-is-serializable/

Answer (score 6):

The function definition

```
def tt[A : TypeTag](a: A) = typeTag[A]
```

is just another way of writing

```
def tt(a: A)(implicit tag: TypeTag[A]) = tag
```

which means that the instance of a tag is being created implicitly by the compiler. The reasoning behind this is that Scala compiler solves the JVM's type erasure problem by hardcoding the otherwise erased type information.

In case you're not familiar with type erasure issue, it is that JVM doesn't store the type parameters information, for instance a type `Seq[Set[Int]]` would be seen simply as `Seq[_]` by the JVM and there would be no way for you to find out the missing type information with reflection.

Comment: I don't think this answer is completely true because there is a way to create Manifests manually which are created by the compiler automatically, too: `new Manifest[Int] {def erasure = classOf[Int]}
` (this doesn't work in 2.10 any more)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve here. Of course you can manually instantiate a class `TypeTag`, but its sole purpose is in being instantiated behind the scene by the compiler, which generates the case-dependent information. If for whatever purpose you're trying to mimic it then your decompiled `private[this] val t: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag` declaration shows exactly how you can do it, but again that's not the way this class was intended to be used.

Comment: A use case for this may be the use of a Scala method which requires a TypeTag from the Java side. I thought: Maybe there is an easier/another way than the way the compiler does it.

Comment: If you're trying to work with Scala reflection api on Scala types from Java source code, then your best bet would be to interface the methods requiring implicit evidence thru some custom api class in Scala. If you're trying to use Scala reflection on Java types in Java it simply won't work. But either way working with Scala reflection from Java is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The following implementation with a macro seems to produce type tags that are serializable and deserializable after serialization

```scala
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.api
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def typeToTypeTag(mirror: api.Mirror[_ <: api.Universe with Singleton])(tpe: mirror.universe.Type): mirror.universe.TypeTag[_] =
  macro typeToTypeTagImpl
// def typeToTypeTag[U <: api.Universe with Singleton](mirror: api.Mirror[U])(tpe: U#Type): U#TypeTag[_] =
//   macro typeToTypeTagImpl

def typeToTypeTagImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(mirror: c.Tree)(tpe: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  val api = q"_root_.scala.reflect.api"
  q"""
    $mirror.universe.TypeTag.apply[$tpe]($mirror,
      new $api.TypeCreator {
        override def apply[U <: $api.Universe with _root_.scala.Singleton](m: $api.Mirror[U]): U#Type = {
          assert(m == $mirror, "TypeTag[" + $tpe + "] defined in " + $mirror + " cannot be migrated to " + m + ".")
          $tpe.asInstanceOf[U#Type]
        }
      }
    )
  """
}
```

[In scala 2.12, why none of the TypeTag created in runtime is serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473734/in-scala-2-12-why-none-of-the-typetag-created-in-runtime-is-serializable/)

This macro produces a type tag tree (when typechecked)

```scala
// -Xprint:typer -Xprint-types
//scalac: performing macro expansion Macro.typeToTypeTag{(mirror: scala.reflect.api.Mirror[_ <: scala.reflect.api.Universe with Singleton])(tpe: mirror.universe.Type): mirror.universe.TypeTag[_]}(App.this{App.type}.m{scala.reflect.api.Mirror[reflect.runtime.universe.type]}){(tpe: App.m.universe.Type): App.m.universe.TypeTag[_]}(App.this{App.type}.tpe{reflect.runtime.universe.Type}){App.m.universe.TypeTag[_$2]}
scalac: App.this{App.type}.m.universe.TypeTag.apply{[T](mirror1: scala.reflect.api.Mirror[scala.reflect.api.Mirror[reflect.runtime.universe.type]#universe.type], tpec1: scala.reflect.api.TypeCreator): scala.reflect.api.Mirror[reflect.runtime.universe.type]#universe.TypeTag[T]}[App.this{App.type}.tpe{reflect.runtime.universe.Type}]{(mirror1: scala.reflect.api.Mirror[scala.reflect.api.Mirror[reflect.runtime.universe.type]#universe.type], tpec1: scala.reflect.api.TypeCreator): scala.reflect.api.Mirror[reflect.runtime.universe.type]#universe.TypeTag[reflect.runtime.universe.Type]}(App.this{App.type}.m{scala.reflect.api.Mirror[reflect.runtime.universe.type]}, {
  final class $anon extends _root_.scala.reflect.api.TypeCreator {
    def <init>(): <$anon: scala.reflect.api.TypeCreator> = {
      $anon.super{super.type}.<init>{(): scala.reflect.api.TypeCreator}(){scala.reflect.api.TypeCreator};
      (){Unit}
    }{Unit};
    override def apply[U <: scala.reflect.api.Universe with Singleton](m: scala.reflect.api.Mirror[U]): U#Type = {
      scala.Predef.assert{(assertion: Boolean, message: => Any): Unit}(m.=={(x$1: Any): Boolean}(App.this{App.type}.m{scala.reflect.api.Mirror[reflect.runtime.universe.type]}){Boolean}, "TypeTag["{String("TypeTag[")}.+{(x$1: Any): String}(App.this{App.type}.tpe{reflect.runtime.universe.Type}){String}.+{(x$1: Any): String}("] defined in "{String("] defined in ")}){String}.+{(x$1: Any): String}(App.this{App.type}.m{scala.reflect.api.Mirror[reflect.runtime.universe.type]}){String}.+{(x$1: Any): String}(" cannot be migrated to "{String(" cannot be migrated to ")}){String}.+{(x$1: Any): String}(m{scala.reflect.api.Mirror[U]}){String}.+{(x$1: Any): String}("."{String(".")}){String}){Unit};
      App.this{App.type}.tpe.asInstanceOf{[T0]T0}[U#Type]{U#Type}
    }{U#Type}
  };
  new $anon{scala.reflect.api.TypeCreator}{(): scala.reflect.api.TypeCreator}(){scala.reflect.api.TypeCreator}
}{scala.reflect.api.TypeCreator}){scala.reflect.api.Mirror[reflect.runtime.universe.type]#universe.TypeTag[reflect.runtime.universe.Type]}
```

different from original

```scala
//scalac: performing macro expansion scala.reflect.api.`package`.materializeTypeTag{[T](u: scala.reflect.api.Universe): u.TypeTag[T]}[Int => String]{(u: scala.reflect.api.Universe): u.TypeTag[Int => String]}(scala.reflect.runtime.`package`.universe{reflect.runtime.universe.type}){reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Int => String]} 
scalac: {
  val $u: reflect.runtime.universe.type = scala.reflect.runtime.`package`.universe{reflect.runtime.universe.type};
  val $m: $u.Mirror = scala.reflect.runtime.`package`.universe.runtimeMirror{(cl: ClassLoader): reflect.runtime.universe.Mirror}(this{App.type}.getClass{(): Class[_ <: App.type]}(){Class[T]}.getClassLoader{(): ClassLoader}(){ClassLoader}){reflect.runtime.universe.Mirror};
  $u.TypeTag.apply{[T](mirror1: scala.reflect.api.Mirror[$u.type], tpec1: scala.reflect.api.TypeCreator): $u.TypeTag[T]}[Int => String]{(mirror1: scala.reflect.api.Mirror[$u.type], tpec1: scala.reflect.api.TypeCreator): $u.TypeTag[Int => String]}($m{$u.Mirror}, {
    final class $typecreator1 extends TypeCreator {
      def <init>(): $typecreator1 = {
        $typecreator1.super{$typecreator1.super.type}.<init>{(): scala.reflect.api.TypeCreator}(){scala.reflect.api.TypeCreator};
        (){Unit}
      }{Unit};
      def apply[U <: scala.reflect.api.Universe with Singleton]($m$untyped: scala.reflect.api.Mirror[U]): U#Type = {
        val $u: U = $m$untyped.universe{$m$untyped.universe.type};
        val $m: $u.Mirror = $m$untyped.asInstanceOf{[T0]T0}[$u.Mirror]{$u.Mirror};
        $u.internal.reificationSupport.TypeRef{(pre: $u.Type, sym: $u.Symbol, args: List[$u.Type]): $u.Type}($u.internal.reificationSupport.ThisType{(sym: $u.Symbol): $u.Type}($m.staticPackage{(fullName: String): $u.ModuleSymbol}("scala"{String("scala")}){$u.ModuleSymbol}.asModule.moduleClass{$u.Symbol}){$u.Type}, $m.staticClass{(fullName: String): $u.ClassSymbol}("scala.Function1"{String("scala.Function1")}){$u.ClassSymbol}, scala.collection.immutable.List.apply{[A](elems: A*): List[A]}[$u.Type]{(elems: $u.Type*): List[$u.Type]}($m.staticClass{(fullName: String): $u.ClassSymbol}("scala.Int"{String("scala.Int")}){$u.ClassSymbol}.asType.toTypeConstructor{$u.Type}, $u.internal.reificationSupport.TypeRef{(pre: $u.Type, sym: $u.Symbol, args: List[$u.Type]): $u.Type}($u.internal.reificationSupport.SingleType{(pre: $u.Type, sym: $u.Symbol): $u.Type}($m.staticPackage{(fullName: String): $u.ModuleSymbol}("scala"{String("scala")}){$u.ModuleSymbol}.asModule.moduleClass.asType.toTypeConstructor{$u.Type}, $m.staticModule{(fullName: String): $u.ModuleSymbol}("scala.Predef"{String("scala.Predef")}){$u.ModuleSymbol}){$u.Type}, $u.internal.reificationSupport.selectType{(owner: $u.Symbol, name: String): $u.TypeSymbol}($m.staticModule{(fullName: String): $u.ModuleSymbol}("scala.Predef"{String("scala.Predef")}){$u.ModuleSymbol}.asModule.moduleClass{$u.Symbol}, "String"{String("String")}){$u.TypeSymbol}, scala.collection.immutable.Nil{List[Nothing]}){$u.Type}){List[$u.Type]}){$u.Type}
      }{$u.Type}
    };
    new $typecreator1{$typecreator1}{(): $typecreator1}(){$typecreator1}
  }{$typecreator1}){$u.TypeTag[Int => String]}
}{$u.TypeTag[Int => String]}
```

but it seems to be working

```scala
val tpe: Type = typeOf[Int => String]
val ttag: TypeTag[_] = typeToTypeTag(m)(tpe)
ttag.tpe =:= tpe // true
```

For original type tag tree the methods [`scala.reflect.api.materializeTypeTag`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.10/src/reflect/scala/reflect/api/package.scala#L59), [`scala.tools.reflect.FastTrack#context2taggers`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.10/src/compiler/scala/tools/reflect/FastTrack.scala#L36) ([L63](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.10/src/compiler/scala/tools/reflect/FastTrack.scala#L63)), [`scala.reflect.reify.Taggers#materializeTypeTag`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.10/src/compiler/scala/reflect/reify/Taggers.scala#L52), [`scala.reflect.reify.reifyType`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.10/src/compiler/scala/reflect/reify/package.scala#L58) should be considered:

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/e9119ea0842479ec0c897660812e38f4 (static type `T` instead of `tpe: Type`, compiler internals).

It's possible that original type tag tree can't be restored from runtime type `tpe: Type` on contrary to static `T`.