# Get TypeTag[A] from Class[A]

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

I have `createOld` method that I need to override and I cannot change it. I would like to use `TypeTag` to pattern match provided type in `createNew`. The goal is to find out how to call `createNew` from `createOld`. My current understanding is that compiler doesn't have enough type information about `A` in `createOld` method if it doesn't already come with `TypeTag[A]`.

```
object TypeTagFromClass {
  class C1
  class C2

  // How to get TypeTag[A] needed by createNew?
  def createOld[A](c: Class[A]): A = createNew ???

  def createNew[A : TypeTag]: A = {
    val result = typeOf[A] match {
      case a if a =:= typeOf[C1] => new C1()
      case a if a =:= typeOf[C2] => new C2()
    }
    result.asInstanceOf[A]
  }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, you cannot materialize a `TypeTag` out of thin air in the implementation of `createOld` in you cannot change `createOld`'s signature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible to create a `TypeTag` from a `Class` using Scala reflection, though I'm not sure if this implementation of `TypeCreator` is absolutely correct:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def createOld[A](c: Class[A]): A = createNew {
  val mirror = runtimeMirror(c.getClassLoader)  // obtain runtime mirror
  val sym = mirror.staticClass(c.getName)  // obtain class symbol for `c`
  val tpe = sym.selfType  // obtain type object for `c`
  // create a type tag which contains above type object
  TypeTag(mirror, new TypeCreator {
    def apply[U <: Universe with Singleton](m: api.Mirror[U]) =
      if (m eq mirror) tpe.asInstanceOf[U # Type]
      else throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Type tag defined in $mirror cannot be migrated to other mirrors.")
  })    
}
```

However, you don't really need full `TypeTag` if you don't need to inspect generic parameters and full Scala type information. You can use `ClassTag`s for that:

```
def createNew[A: ClassTag]: A = {
  val result = classTag[A].runtimeClass match {
    case a if a.isAssignableFrom(classOf[C1]) => new C1()
    case a if a.isAssignableFrom(classOf[C2]) => new C2()
  }
  result.asInstanceOf[A]
}
```

Or with some implicit sugar:

```
implicit class ClassTagOps[T](val classTag: ClassTag[T]) extends AnyVal {
  def <<:(other: ClassTag[_]) = classTag.runtimeClass.isAssignableFrom(other.runtimeClass)
}

def createNew[A: ClassTag]: A = {
  val result = classTag[A] match {
    case a if a <<: classTag[C1] => new C1()
    case a if a <<: classTag[C2] => new C2()
  }
  result.asInstanceOf[A]
}
```

You can simplify that even further by using plain old Java `newInstance()` method:

```
def createNew[A: ClassTag]: A = classTag[A].runtimeClass.newInstance().asInstanceOf[A]
```

This, of course, would only work if you don't need different constructor parameters for different classes.

Calling this `createNew` from `createOld` is much simpler than the one with `TypeTag`s:

```
def createOld[A](c: Class[A]): A = createNew(ClassTag[A](c))
```

Comment: Fixed `TypeTag` creation code, it was somewhat incomplete.

Comment: Are you sure about the last line? `createNew(ClassTag(c))` doesn't make much sense neither to me nor to the compiler.

Comment: @RadoBuransky, yes, I'm pretty sure. If `createNew` is declared as `def createNew[A: ClassTag]`, it is equivalent to `def createNew[A](implicit ct: ClassTag[A])`, so you can call this method providing implicit argument explicitly. That said, you probably should pass type parameter to `ClassTag.apply` method: `createNew(ClassTag[A](c))`. Don't forget to import `ClassTag` first: `import scala.reflect.ClassTag`.

Answer (score 1):

So it is not very safe and correct (cause you don't use the power of scala type system), but you can make (using your logic) to do the following:

```
def createNew[A](implicit t: TypeTag[A]): A = {
  val result: Any = t.tpe.toString match {
    case "C1" => new C1
    case "C2" => new C2
  }
  result.asInstanceOf[A]
}

createNew[C1] //> its all ok
createNew[C2] //> its all ok
createNew[C3] //> crashes here; lets pretend we got C3 class
```

To use it with `createOld`, just pass implicit argument:

```
def createOld[A](c: Class[A])(implicit t: TypeTag[A]): A = createNew[A]

createOld[C1] //> its all ok
createOld[C2] //> its all ok
createOld[C3] //> crashes here; lets pretend we got C3 class
```

I think I should not tell you twice that it is not very good.
We can improve this code by using `shapeless`:

Lets create a poly function, which has a `TypeTag` as an argument:

```
 import shapeless._; import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._;

 def getTypeTag[T](implicit t: TypeTag[T]) = t //> to get TypeTag of a class

 // here is low prority implicit
 trait createPolyNewErr extends Poly1 {
   implicit def newErr[T] = at[T](_ => "Error can not create object of this class")
 } 

 object createPolyBew extends createPolyNewError {
   implicit def newC1 = at[TypeTag[C1]](_ => new C1)
   implicit def newC2 = at[TypeTag[C2]](_ => new C2)
 }

 createPolyNew(getTypeTag[C1]) //> success
 createPolyNew(getTypeTag[C2]) //> success
 createPolyNew(getTypeTag[C3]) //> String: Error can not create object of this class no crash!
```

We also can write a function, in order not to use function `getTypeTag[T]` every time:

```
 def createPoly[T]
 (implicit t: TypeTag[T],
         cse: poly.Case[createPolyNew.type, TypeTag[T] :: HNil]) = cse(t)

 createPoly[C1] //> its all ok
 createPoly[C2] //> its all ok
 createPoly[C3] //> String: Error can not create object of this class no crash!
```

Comment: As far as I understand this `def createOld[A](c: Class[A])(implicit t: TypeTag[A])` won't work because topic starter needs to override existing method (possibly coming from Java), and overriding only works on methods with the same signature, and adding an implicit parameter is obviously an incompatible change to the signature. Or maybe I don't understand something?

Comment: Hm, dunno, can he or can not pass implicit argument, mb you are right, then this would not work, however it is rather dirty way to build objects in a such way. :)

Comment: Yeah, agree with that, but sometimes we just have to work with nasty APIs :)

Comment: @VladimirMatveev is right. I cannot add `(implicit t: TypeTag[A])` to the method signature.