# TypeTag in current trait

Tags: class, scala, generics

As far as I know, I can use `this` in a method to reference to the current object/class, even if the method is in a trait. But how can I use TypeTags of the class referenced with `this`?

Something like `val i: TypeTag[T] = typeTag[this]` would work for me.

A similar problem is already questioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970209/get-typetaga-from-classa), but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like

```
object Example {
  val i = typeTag[this.type]
}
```