# Getting TypeTag from a classname string

Tags: scala, reflection

Simple question, how does one get a `TypeTag` from a classname?

So basically the `TypeTag` equivalent of `Class.forName` in Java.

Note: Manifest won't do for me here, I need a TypeTag. Although if there's a way to go from a manifest to a typetag, that would work too, as I can get a Manifest from the classname.

Comment: You could get a `ClassTag`, it seems.

Comment: A class tag might do me. I just want to get the fields of a case class from the FQN of the class. I could hack about with Java reflection if I have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Class.forName` to get a `Class` from a `String`, `ManifestFactory.classType` to get a `Manifest` from the `Class`, and then `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.manifestToTypeTag` to get a `TypeTag`:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.reflect.ManifestFactory

val className = "java.lang.String"
val mirror = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
val cls = Class.forName(className)
val t = universe.manifestToTypeTag(mirror,
                                   ManifestFactory.classType(cls))
```

Comment: Note: this won't work with generics, so it would be better to return `ClassTag` if that's sufficient.

Comment: There is a way of creating a `TypeTag` with generics. Please refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/44666298/396002

Answer (score 13):

Manifests are deprecated and can probably disappear in future Scala versions. I don't think it is wise to rely on them. You can use only new Scala reflection to do what you want.

You can go from a string to a `Class` to get its class loader, and then it is possible to create a `TypeTag` from a `Class` through a mirror, as is outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970209/get-typetaga-from-classa/22972751#22972751). Here is a slightly adapted piece of code demonstrating it:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.api

def stringToTypeTag[A](name: String): TypeTag[A] = {
  val c = Class.forName(name)  // obtain java.lang.Class object from a string
  val mirror = runtimeMirror(c.getClassLoader)  // obtain runtime mirror
  val sym = mirror.staticClass(name)  // obtain class symbol for `c`
  val tpe = sym.selfType  // obtain type object for `c`
  // create a type tag which contains above type object
  TypeTag(mirror, new api.TypeCreator {
    def apply[U <: api.Universe with Singleton](m: api.Mirror[U]) =
      if (m eq mirror) tpe.asInstanceOf[U # Type]
      else throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Type tag defined in $mirror cannot be migrated to other mirrors.")
  })
}
```

Comment: Would this capture nested types? For example, would this work with "List[Int]"?

Comment: No, it won't because `Class.forName` expects proper Java class name.

Comment: What does `[A]` in `stringToTypeTag[A]` mean? I don't think we can provide `A` since we are getting TypeTag for A with class name.

Comment: @Tom that's for ease of usage. Even if you want to get a type tag by the class name, you still need to specify some type because `TypeTag` is parameterized; this definition allows to specify any type you need, which is of course dangerous (no guarantee that it is the same type as the one identified by the class name) but also convenient because you won't need to do `.asInstanceOf`s.