# Construct a TypeTag from a Class?

Tags: scala

Given a class instance, is it possible to create a TypeTag from it?

```
val s = "string"
val klass = s.getClass
// ????
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135248/scala-equivalent-of-java-java-lang-classt-object

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22972751/788207). The first example does exactly what you need.