# Can I use a class defined in a `ToolBox` as a type parameter of `typeOf[]`?

Tags: scala, reflection, runtime, metaprogramming, toolbox

I'd like to experiment with the use of a dynamic data model with a reflective library that uses `typeOf[]`.

I've defined a class at runtime with a Scala reflection `ToolBox` in 2.11:

```
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.{ currentMirror => cm }

def cdef() = q"case class C(v: String)"
val tb = cm.mkToolBox()
val csym = tb.define(cdef())
def newc(csym: Symbol) = q"""new ${csym}("hi")"""
val obj = tb.eval(newc(csym))
```

I'm able to circumvent the `typeOf[]` call by entering Scala reflection via the `ClassSymbol` instead, but that requires modifying a library over which I have no immediate control.

Is there any way that I can use it as a type parameter in a library whose entry point is `typeOf[]`?

**I've tried:**

The only way I found to go from a value to something that I could use in the type position was use Java reflection to invoke the companion class' apply method and call `.type` on the result:

```
val method_apply = obj.getClass.getMethod("apply", "".getClass)
val typeTemplate = method_apply.invoke(obj, "hello")
type MyType = typeTemplate.type
```

(Keeping with the naming scheme of @xeno_by and @travisbrown 's [menagerie of odd types](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/09/02/potemkin-val-age/), I might call this "Frankenstein's Type", because it is made from parts, given life at the wrong time, not quite a substitute for the original, and given that this is all happening at runtime, should probably be burned with fire.)

This type alias works as a type parameter is some cases. But in the case of `typeOf[MyType]`, the the compiler makes a `TypeTag` before the runtime type is defined, so `typeOf[MyType]` returns a type member that doesn't correspond to the runtime type/class (e.g. `TypeTag[package.Example.MyType]` instead of `TypeTag[package.C]`)

Should I expect the `ToolBox` to have generated a `TypeTag`, and if so, how do I use it?

If I have to make a `TypeTag` at runtime, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970209/get-typetaga-from-classa/22972751#22972751) shows me how, but then how do I attach it to whatever I use as a type parameter?

Thanks for any ideas,

-Julian

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want to achieve? What method are you calling that requires you to provide a typeOf?

Comment: Similar to this [example](https://github.com/julianpeeters/toolbox-salat-example/blob/master/src/main/scala/Main.scala#L60) using Salat, but with [Scalavro](https://github.com/GenslerAppsPod/scalavro) instead. It looks like `AvroType[T]` uses an implicit TypeTag to get runtime class info for T, so I assumed (perhaps naively) that if I could do `typeOf[MyType]`

Comment: ...that I could also do `AvroType[MyType]`. [This branch](https://github.com/julianpeeters/toolbox-salat-example/blob/scalavro/src/main/scala/Main.scala) shows the error (that there is no class corresponding to the de-aliased type parameter).

Comment: If it's helpful, [here's](https://github.com/julianpeeters/toolbox-scalavro/commit/a094109d50eabfbaf366261ffa9a9b1675270c42#diff-9d3013c5d648f8bf6caa21997834fa9dR35) a crude fork of Scalavro that shows a workaround by passing in the toolbox and the class symbol.

Comment: Yeah, I think something along these lines will work. You'll need to create a dummy type and then create a fake type tag for that type that contains the scala.reflect.runtime.Type that you would like to pass in. A type alias isn't dummy enough imo, so I'd go for something like `class Foo { type T; implicit val tag: TypeTag[T] = createTypeTag(yourTpe).asInstanceOf[TypeTag[T]] }; val dummy = new Foo; import dummy._`.

Comment: Why did you pass in a toolbox btw?

Comment: That's fantastic. I passed in the toolbox to give Scalavro access to the toolbox's special classloader, so it could use a classloader mirror to reflect on the companion's apply method when mapping default values.