# Implicit classTag and currying

Tags: scala, implicit

I am trying to write a function that returns a `foldLeft` without its last argument, and which I also need to be parametric. I need a `ClassTag` for this parameter, but there seems to be no way I can have both an `implicit ClassTag` and leave room for a scope to complete the function:

```
def fields[T](implicit ctag: ClassTag[T]) : Array[String] =
  ctag.runtimeClass.getDeclaredFields.map(_.getName)

def foldArgs[C](args: Array[String])(implicit ctag: ClassTag[C])
  : ((C, (String, String)) => C) => C = {
   val tt = weakTypeTag[C].tpe
   val clsMirror = universe
     .runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
     .reflectClass(tt.typeSymbol.asClass)
   val ctorSym = tt.decl(universe.termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
   val instance = clsMirror.reflectConstructor(ctorSym)().asInstanceOf[C]
   fields[C].zip(args).foldLeft(instance)
}

case class Config(a: Int, b: Double, c: String)

def fun: (Config, (String, String)) => Config = ???

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  Try { foldArgs[Config](args)(fun) } match {
    case Success(a) => println(a)
    case Failure(e) => println(s"${e.getMessage}")
  }
}
```

The last line in `foldArgs` needs to pass a `ClassTag[C]` to `fields`, but how do I create that `ClassTag[C]`? It seems I have to in turn pass it in as an `implicit` to `foldArgs` itself, which now breaks the call `foldArgs[Config](args)(fun)`: the compiler tells me that there is a type mismatch on `fun` (it's expecting the `ClassTag` for `C` I think). Is there any way to have it both ways, to have a `ClassTag` and `fun`?

Answer (score 1):

You can write it as

```
foldArgs[Config](args).apply(fun)
```

or (worse)

```
foldArgs[Config](args)(implicitly)(fun)
```

(where `implicitly` can specify the type: `implicitly[ClassTag[Config]]`, or can be replaced by `classTag`).

Comment: It works at compile time, but I get `free type C is not a class` at runtime.

Comment: Ah, that's the result of `weakTypeTag[C].tpe`. It just returns the type parameter not bound to anything and so `asClass` fails. I think you don't need it at all and can use `val instance = ctag.runtimeClass.newInstance().asInstanceOf[C]`?

Comment: Wait, no, your constructor needs parameters but you don't pass any in `clsMirror.reflectConstructor(ctorSym)()`. So you need to figure out how you want to handle it. At any rate, only `TypeTag` instead of `WeakTypeTag` can work. You can create it from the `ClassTag` or vice versa (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970209/get-typetaga-from-classa/22972751#22972751 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729321/how-to-get-classtag-form-typetag-or-both-at-same-time)  or just add as another implicit parameter.