# Get a TypeTag from a Type?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

I can get a `Type` from a `TypeTag[A]` by using the `tpe` method. But can I also recover the type-tag from a type?

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
import ru.{Type, TypeTag}

def forward[A](implicit tt: TypeTag[A]): Type = tt.tpe

def backward(t: Type): TypeTag[_] = ???
```

The reason being that I have an API that uses type-tags as keys into a map, but at some point I only have the type and dropped the tag.

Comment: relevant, possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494788/how-to-create-a-typetag-manually

Comment: api changed now - so you can pass `TypeCreator` implementation instead of `TypeFactory`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.api

val mirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)  // whatever mirror you use to obtain the `Type`

def backward[T](tpe: Type): TypeTag[T] =
  TypeTag(mirror, new api.TypeCreator {
    def apply[U <: api.Universe with Singleton](m: api.Mirror[U]) =
      if (m eq mirror) tpe.asInstanceOf[U # Type]
      else throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Type tag defined in $mirror cannot be migrated to other mirrors.")
  })

assert(backward[String](forward[String]) == typeTag[String])
```

Comment: where do `TypeCreator`, `api` and `Universe` come from?

Comment: NB. This method prevent the TypeTag from being serialized. Throws: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror
Compiler generated typetag seem to be serializable.

Comment: @user48956 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473734/in-scala-2-12-why-none-of-the-typetag-created-in-runtime-is-serializable/