# Cast some object with the help of its Type

Tags: scala, reflection

Is it possible to cast some object with the help of its `Type`. For example:

```
import scala.reflect.api.Types

val t: Types#Type = ...// real type of the object o below
println(t)            // out: com.project.Event[java.lang.String]
val o: Any = ...       // some object which has above type


val e: com.project.Event[java.lang.String] = cast(o, t)

def cast(o: Any, t: Type) = ???
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use exactly `Type` (not `TypeTag[T]`) - in general case no, because  the instance of `Type` doesn't store any information in compile-time: there is no type-level members/parameters storing that info.

So if you use `Type` in runtime - there is no way to know which compile-time type it's corresponding to (what is the return type of your cast function? `_`? :) ).

So your cast would have to have a signature like:

```
def cast[T](o: Any, t: Type): T = o.asInstanceOf[T]
```

in which case `Type` doesn't really help as (unlike `TypeTag[T]`) it doesn't provide anything for type inference of `T`. Even [conversion from Type to `TypeTag[T]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887386/get-a-typetag-from-a-type) obviously requires you to specify type explicitly, like `cast[String]` and so on.

The only thing `Type` can be used for is to check if `o` actually corresponds `t`:

```
def cast[T](o: Any, t: Type): Option[T] = 
  if (mirror.reflect(o).symbol == t.typeSymbol) Some(o.asInstanceOf[T]) else None
```

up to something like:

```
def cast[T: TypeTag](o: Any, t: Type): Option[T] = 
  if (mirror.reflect(o).symbol == t.typeSymbol && typeOf[T] =:= t)
    Some(o.asInstanceOf[T]) 
  else None
```

---

One obvious exception is when you obtained a `Type` inside a macro, so you can compose a tree with correct `asInstanceOf` in compile-time:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/3YF_98W9eSE

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [TypeTag](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) for holding the **type info** and cast it to the target type, like:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

// get TypeTag by typeTag[A]
val t: TypeTag[com.project.Event[java.lang.String]] = typeTag[com.project.Event[java.lang.String]]

//cast with typeTag
val r:com.project.Event[java.lang.String]  = cast(o, t)
def cast[A](o: Any, t: TypeTag[A]) = o.asInstanceOf[A]
```

if you can't get `TypeTag` directly, maybe you want to convert the `Type` to `TypeTag`:

[Get a TypeTag from a Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887386/get-a-typetag-from-a-type)