# Least common TypeTag from two tags in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-macros

Scala's TypeTags are relatively easy to compare, and capture - but does Scala offer any composition function that act on 2 tags? For example, I'm working with tags in a very generalized way (meaning, type T is gone). Can I request Scala to provide me a TypeTag of the least common parent? This would seem logical since the compiler and various editor IDEs do this with ease and show the common parent. Example:

```
Class A
Class B extends A
class C extends A

val tagB:TypeTag[_] =  implicitly[TypeTag[B]]
val tagC:TypeTag[_] =  implicitly[TypeTag[C]]

val res:TypeTag[_] = lcmFunction(tagB,tagC)  //not a real function name .. example only

res  // yields a TypeTag such that res.tpe =:= TypeTag[A].tpe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `lub` method on `Universe`, which will compute the least upper-bound of a list of types.

```
class A
class B extends A
class C extends A
class D extends C
class E extends C
class F extends E

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

val a = typeTag[A]
val b = typeTag[B]
val c = typeTag[C]
val d = typeTag[D]
val e = typeTag[E]
val f = typeTag[F]

scala> lub(List(b.tpe, c.tpe))
res17: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = A

scala> lub(List(b.tpe, c.tpe)) =:= a.tpe
res18: Boolean = true

scala> lub(List(e.tpe, f.tpe))
res19: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = E

scala> lub(List(c.tpe, d.tpe, f.tpe))
res21: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = C
```

Creating a `TypeTag` out of the resulting `Type` is a little more tricky, it seems, but possible as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25691045/2292812).