# In Scala, What is the difference between universe.TypeTag, TypeRef, and Type?

Tags: scala, dynamic, scala-reflect

There are 3 different classes all bounded to a universe: `TypeTag`, `TypeRef`, and `Type`. Why do we need all 3? If I only have a `Type`, how do I convert it to a `TypeTag` or `TypeRef`?

E.g. I have obtain a common super type through a Scala reflection API function:

```
val at = ...some TypeTag...
val bt = ...some TypeTag...

val tpe = ScalaReflection.universe.lub(List(at.tpe, bt.tpe))
ScalaReflection.universe.(tpe)
```

How do I convert it into `TypeTag` or `TypeRef`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TypeRef` is a specific case of `Type`:

```
abstract type TypeRef >: Null <: Universe.TypeRefApi with Universe.Type
```

You can check if a `Type` is actually a `TypeRef` by pattern-matching:

```
tpe match {
  case TypeRef(prefix, sym, args) =>
  // or alternately
  case typeRef: TypeRef =>
}
```

`TypeTag[A]` is a way to get access to `Type` which 1) works for different mirrors; 2) can be generated by the compiler automatically from the type parameter (note that `Type` is not generic).

To convert `Type` to `TypeTag`, from [How to create a TypeTag manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494788/how-to-create-a-typetag-manually/25691045#25691045):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def typeToTypeTag[T](
  tpe: Type,
  mirror: reflect.api.Mirror[reflect.runtime.universe.type]
): TypeTag[T] = {
  TypeTag(mirror, new reflect.api.TypeCreator {
    def apply[U <: reflect.api.Universe with Singleton](m: reflect.api.Mirror[U]) = {
      assert(m eq mirror, s"TypeTag[$tpe] defined in $mirror cannot be migrated to $m.")
      tpe.asInstanceOf[U#Type]
    }
  })
}
```