# Given a Type, create an Option Type that contains it

Tags: scala, reflection

Given a `Type` named `inner`, I would like to create a new `Type` that represents an `Option` containing a type of the same type as `inner`.

For example, the signature of a method that would do this may look something like:

```
def createOptionType(inner: Type): Type = {
  typeOf[Option[inner]] // this line is pseudocode
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25691045/446554) helps partially, but makes use of a generic method, whereas in this case I have a concrete type passed in, making generics unuseable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.appliedType` for that:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def createOptionType(inner: Type): Type = 
  appliedType(typeOf[Option[_]], inner)
```