# In Scala, how to create a TypeTag from a type that is serializable?

Tags: scala, reflection, types, scala-reflect

In Scala reflection, the TypeTag can usually be constructed from a Type using a TypeCreator:

```
object TypeUtils {

  import ScalaReflection.universe._

  def createTypeTag[T](
      tpe: Type,
      mirror: reflect.api.Mirror[reflect.runtime.universe.type]
  ): TypeTag[T] = {
    TypeTag.apply(
      mirror,
      NaiveTypeCreator(tpe)
    )
  }

  case class NaiveTypeCreator(tpe: Type) extends reflect.api.TypeCreator {

    def apply[U <: reflect.api.Universe with Singleton](
        m: reflect.api.Mirror[U]): U#Type = {
      //          assert(m eq mirror, s"TypeTag[$tpe] defined in $mirror cannot be migrated to $m.")
      tpe.asInstanceOf[U#Type]
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately, it turns out the output of `createTypeTag` is not serializable, unlike the typeTag created from compile-time inference:

```
import java.io.{ByteArrayOutputStream, ObjectOutputStream}

import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection
import org.scalatest.FunSpec

class TypeTagFromType extends FunSpec {

  import ScalaReflection.universe._

  it("create TypeTag from reflection") {

    val ttg = typeTag[String]

    val ttg2 = TypeUtils.createTypeTag(ttg.tpe, ttg.mirror)

    Seq(
      ttg -> "from static inference",
      ttg2 -> "from dynamic type"
    ).foreach {
      case (tt, k) =>
        println(k)

        val bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        try {
          val out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)
          out.writeObject(tt)
          out.flush()
          val array = bos.toByteArray
        } finally {
          bos.close()
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This gives the output:

```
from static inference
from dynamic type


scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$anon$2
java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$anon$2
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
```

Indicating that the second TypeTag is not serializable, while the first one is.

So my question is: how to make the second TypeTag to be serializable like the first one?

I'm using scala 2.12.10 at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [How to create a TypeTag manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44666298/5205022)

> if you need a serializable `TypeTag` and performance isn't your main
>   concern

then consider

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

def createTypeTag(tp: Type): TypeTag[_] = {
  val toolbox = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
  val ttree = toolbox.parse(s"scala.reflect.runtime.universe.typeTag[$tp]")
  toolbox.eval(ttree).asInstanceOf[TypeTag[_]]
}

val ttg = typeTag[List[String]]
val ttg2 = createTypeTag(ttg.tpe)
...
```

Comment: I believe that answer is kind of obsolete, The mirror class doesn't have the 'mkToolBox' method and produce a compilation error. I'll ask it again under a new title since this one is marked as duplicated

Comment: @tribbloid The answer is not obsolete. The code compiles in 2.12.10, 2.13.1. You just need one more import `import scala.reflect.runtime.universe` (besides `import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._`). `mkToolBox` is in `ToolBoxFactory` here https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/reflect/ToolBoxFactory.scala#L35 And implicit conversion from `Mirror` to `ToolBoxFactory` is here https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/reflect/package.scala#L25

Comment: I see, thanks a lot! let me try

Comment: Nice it works! But still I'm a bit disappointed that Such simple thing has to be accomplished by string manipulation

Comment: Oops, just found that serialisation works, but deserialisation fails: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: __wrapper$1$2044369228ff48bb85c06775c7f0d775.__wrapper$1$2044369228ff48bb85c06775c7f0d775$$typecreator1$1

Comment: Already asked a new question according to suggestion, thanks a lot for your help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473734/in-scala-2-12-why-none-of-the-typetag-created-in-runtime-is-serializable