# How to compare the return type of a method to a Scala native or TypeTag?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

So, I'm using the Scala reflections library, and I'm trying to check if a method conforms to a given type. To simplify, I'm trying to check only its output.

What I have now is:

```scala
val returnType = methodSymbol.returnType
// returnType: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = java.lang.String
```

So, I can read it is a String, but it has this terrible type `reflect.runtime.universe.Type`. How on Earth can I compare check if this return type is a simple String? I even tried using TypeTags, which are simple enough, but to convert a `Type` to a `TypeTag` is such a monumental effort that I fail to believe such a simple task cannot be achieved with more simply.

So, how can I compare this to a String and simply get a boolean back?
I thought of simply calling a `toString()` and trying to parse that back to a normal type, but that would be really disgusting to do on the code, IMO. Also, I cannot simply specify the method name, because I'm working on a list of methods, and more will come later.

I've seen some questions, and even this (in my opinion, absurdly complex) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44666298/7269570) on how to convert a Type to a TypeTag, but, again, I'm baffled by the level of complexity for such a trivial task. I'm already thinking of pulling my scarce hair out. Help appreciated.

EDIT: I've managed to make the comparison for the String itself, but not for a method returning the String.

To compare the String return type, I'm doing:

```scala
val returnType = methodSymbol.returnType
returnType =:= typeTag[String].tpe
```

When I try to check it with inheritance and a method, though, using `<:<`, it won't work. To clarify, B extends Trait A, the type signature is `() => B`, but I cannot match when coding

```scala
val typeSig = methodSymbol.typeSig
typeSig <:< typeTag[() => A].tpe
```

Comment: Why do you need to check the return type of a method against a string? Reflection is usually discouraged in **Scala** so it is no surprise that it is hard to do _"simple"_ things.

Comment: Why not just do `returnType == typeOf[String]`?

Comment: Well, I do not need to check against a String. I need to make sure some methods in a given object conform to an expected pattern - I want them taking no arguments as inputs, and returning a given type. String is a simple example. I cannot compare directly to the typeTag because that comparison simply doesn't work, given `returnType` is not a TypeTag, as stated previously.

Comment: `typeOf` returns a `Type`, not a `TypeTag`, as far as I know. See this Scastie playground: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/sQDO2hDJThyKuUiWaZWRmQ

Comment: I'm sorry. I misunderstood - though you were talking about `typeTag`. My bad. Anyway, I tried to do that and it returned a funny ` found:  ru.Type / required: reflect.runtime.universe.Type`. Using the typeTag and converting it to a type, it is now working, although not matching the inheritance.

Comment: That's odd. `ru` *is* `scala.reflect.runtime.universe`

Comment: I agree. I didn't even try to understand, because it made no sense to me. Using typeTag worked partially, so, I'm ok-ish

Comment: Would Java reflection be sufficient for your use case? It's far easier to use.

Comment: Well, not exactly, but I can mix both (I'm already doing that, to be honest), and get what I need from there.

Comment: @LucasLima if `returnType` is `B` why do you check `returnType <:< typeTag[() => B].tpe` (which is `returnType <:< typeOf[() => B]`)? This can't be true.

Comment: Because I'm stupid and typed it wrongly. Going to fix it.

Comment: @LucasLima `returnType <:< typeOf[() => A]` returns `true` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/4q5BilFTSQCSw3UTkufvxQ

Comment: @LucasLima if for you `returnType <:< typeOf[() => A]` gives `false` then you should provide more details how to reproduce your behavior (write the whole code).

Comment: @LucasLima If `returnType` is obtained from `MethodSymbol` then anyway `returnType <:< typeOf[() => A]` returns `true` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/UQBTG9ytTv2Pgwn8RxlVEw

Comment: That was a  misconception on my end. I assumed that `returnType` and `typeSignature` would return the same sort of object - it is not true. Indeed, with `returnType`, it works alright. Imma correct the question (once again) and accept your ansser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to work with types as `String`s you should parse them

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

val tb = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
val str = "java.lang.String"
val tpe: Type = (tb.typecheck(tb.parse(s"type T = $str"), mode = tb.TYPEmode) match {
  case q"type T = $typ" => typ
}).tpe // String
tpe =:= typeOf[String] //true
```

(I would like to do just `tb.typecheck(tb.parse(str/*, mode = ???*/), mode = tb.TYPEmode).tpe` but can't find how to call `TypeParser` instead of `TermParser` with runtime reflection, this corresponds to difference between `tq"..."` and `q"..."`, otherwise I get `String` companion instead of `String` itself. Surely `tq"$str"` gives wrong type too because it's a macro, it can work only for compile-time literals: `tq"java.lang.String"`.)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe not exactly what you're asking for, but you can use `java.lang.reflect` in Scala.

```scala
import java.lang.reflect.Method

class C {
  def doSomething(): String = {
    return "hello"
  }
  def doSomethingElse(): String = {
    return "bye"
  }
  def doNothing(): Int = {
    return 190
  }
}

val doSomethingMethod: Method = classOf[C].getMethods()(2)
val doNothingMethod: Method = classOf[C].getMethods()(1)
val doSomethingElseMethod: Method = classOf[C].getMethods()(0)

// false
doSomethingMethod.getReturnType.equals(doNothingMethod.getReturnType)

// true
doSomethingMethod.getReturnType.equals(doSomethingMethod.getReturnType)

// you can compare the simple name, too, if that's easier
println(s"'${doSomethingMethod.getReturnType.getSimpleName}'")
// 'String'
```