# Scala - type erasure?

Tags: scala, types, type-erasure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get around type erasure on Scala? Or, why can't I get the type parameter of my collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete)

I ran the following code:

```
scala>  var s = new Stack()push(1)
s: scalatest.Stack[Int] = 1 

scala>  s match { case s : Stack[String] => print("Hello")}
<console>:12: warning: non variable type-argument String in type pattern scalatest.Stack[String] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
              s match { case s : Stack[String] => print("Hello")
}
```

Stack is the class taken from http://www.scala-lang.org/node/129. If I run this code without `-unchecked` flag it will print "Hello". Why is that the case?

Comment: The compiler is telling you that there is a problem, and what is it. Why are you asking about it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're matching `s` to be of type `Stack[String]`. During runtime, it's possible to determine if `s` is of type `Stack`, but because of Java's [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) it's not possible to determine if `s` is of type `Stack[String]`, `Stack[Int]` etc. So no matter what the type parameter was, it gets matched by the `case` expression. This is why Scala issues the warning. It is the same as if you match as

```
s match { case s : Stack[_] => print("Hello")}
```

(which will compile without warnings).

---

**Edit:** A workaround (for Java too) is to create a specific class that doesn't have type parameters any more. For example:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Stack;

object Test extends App {
  class MyStack extends Stack[Int];
  class MyOtherStack extends Stack[String];

  val s: Stack[_] = new MyStack().push(1);

  s match {
    case s : MyOtherStack => print("Hello String");
    case s : MyStack => print("Hello Int");
  }
}
```

It has a drawback that you cannot use it for immutable containers, because their methods create new objects and they won't be instances of these our specific subclasses.

Comment: ah, OK... so the generics are not reified in Scala then