# Where does Manifest in the implicit method parameter list ome from?

Tags: scala

I tried a example from another post: [How do I get around type erasure on Scala? Or, why can't I get the type parameter of my collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete). and following is the workable example:

```
object Registry {
   import scala.reflect.Manifest

   private var map = Map.empty[Any, (Manifest[_], Any)]

   def register[T](name: Any, item: T)(implicit m: Manifest[T]) {
      map = map.updated(name, m -> item)
   }

   def get[T](key: Any)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): Option[T] = {
     map get key flatMap {
      case (om, s) => if (om <:< m) Some(s.asInstanceOf[T]) else None
   }
  }
}

object App extends App {
   Registry.register("a", List(1, 2, 3))

   println(Registry.get[List[Int]]("a"))
   //Some(List(1, 2, 3))
  }
```

I have 2 questions:

1. There is one implicit parameter m: Manifest[T] for method register, I think this parameter should be defined somewhere to be used. But there is no definition, why is it usable?
2. This line: `case (om, s) => if (om <:< m) Some(s.asInstanceOf[T]) else None`, in method `get`, what does `om <:< m` mean? It is the first time I saw such usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Manifest implicits are inserted by the compiler (when it can produce them).
2. `om <:< m` checks that the type represented by the manifest `om` is a subtype of the type represented by the manifest `m`.

Notes:

- Manifests are replaced by TypeTags in Scala 2.10
- The `<:<` method on Manifests is not always accurate (it could e.g. ignore covariance/contravariance annotations on type parameters, IIRC).