# Casting String to Int using scala extractors

Tags: scala, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, unapply

I am trying to cast a `String` to `Int` using extractors. My code looks as follows.

```
object Apply {
  def unapply(s: String): Option[Int] = try {
    Some(s.toInt)
  } catch {
    case _: java.lang.Exception => None
  }
}

object App {
  def toT[T](s: AnyRef): Option[T] = s match {
    case v: T => Some(v)
    case _ => None
  }
  def foo(param: String): Int = {
    //reads a Map[String,String] m at runtime
    toT[Int](m("offset")).getOrElse(0)
  }
}
```

I get a runtime error: `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`. It seems the extractor is not being used at all. What should I do?

**Edit:** My use case is as follows. I am using play and I want to parse the query string passed in the url. I want to take the query string value (String) and use it as an Int, Double etc. For example,

```
val offset = getQueryStringAs[Int]("offset").getOrElse(0)
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to be used?

Comment: You tagged the question with "implicit-conversion", there is no implicit conversion going on your code.

Comment: `toT[T] ... case v:T` will not work, T is lost in erasure.

Comment: It is fundamentally impossible to **cast** a `String` to any other type (except for `AnyRef` or `Any`).

Comment: Oh, I did try an implicit def but that didn't work.

Comment: @pedrofurla I have added my use case.

Comment: If you are using play 2.1.0 (with scala 2.10) you can define "extension" methods" on `String`: `implicit class StringConversionOps(val str: String) extends AnyVal { def parseInt = try { Some(str.toInt) } catch { case _ => None } }`. You can add methods to that class as necessary. Then assuming it's in scope you can do `m("offset").parseInt.getOrElse(0)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the biggest problem here is, that you seem to confuse casting and conversion. You have a `Map[String, String]` and therefore you can't cast the values to `Int`. You have to convert them. Luckily Scala adds the `toInt` method to strings through implicit conversion to StringOps.

This should work for you:

```
m("offset").toInt
```

Note that `toInt` will throw a `java.lang.NumberFormatException` if the string can not be converted to an integer.

**edit**:

What you want will afaik only work with typeclasses.

Here is an example:

```
trait StringConverter[A] {
  def convert(x: String): A
}

implicit object StringToInt extends StringConverter[Int] {
  def convert(x: String): Int = x.toInt
}

implicit object StringToDouble extends StringConverter[Double] {
  def convert(x: String): Double = x.toDouble
}

implicit def string2StringConversion(x: String) = new {
  def toT[A](implicit ev: StringConverter[A]) = ev.convert(x)
}
```

usage:

```
scala> "0.".toT[Double]
res6: Double = 0.0
```

Comment: That is fine, but what I want is a toT[T] method which works generically.

Comment: Ok thanks, is this the only way this could be done? Why shouldn't a type match work?

Comment: Because 1) your values are of type string and 2) `T` will be erased and not available at runtime (this can actually be fixed with using `Manifest`/`TypeTag`, but still you have strings, that you have to convert).

Comment: Ok, I'll use use typeclasses then, with an Option[A] return type for convert

Comment: Why is this happening?

    scala> "0".toT[Int]
    res1: Option[Int] = Some(0)
    
    scala> def foo[T](s: String): Option[T] = s.toT[T]
    <console>:10: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: StringConverter[T]
           def foo[T](s: String): Option[T] = s.toT[T]
                                               ^

Comment: To clarify, I can do "0".toT[Int] but, I can't create a function foo[A] that calls toT[A], and foo[Int] is called somewhere else

Comment: Because there is no instance for `StringConverter[T]`. Try `def foo[A : StringConverter]`, this is called a type bound and adds an implicit params of type `StringConverter[A]` to your method, that is then used for the call to `toT[A]`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem in your code, for which you should have received compiler warnings:

```
def toT[T](s: AnyRef): Option[T] = s match {
  case v: T => Some(v) // this doesn't work, because T is erased
  case _ => None
}
```

Now... where should `Apply` have been used? I see it declared, but I don't see it used anywhere.

**EDIT**

About the warning, look at the discussions around *type erasure* on Stack Overflow. For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1094214/53013) I wrote on how to get around it -- though it's now deprecated with Scala 2.10.0.

To solve your problem I'd use type classes. For example:

```
abstract class Converter[T] {
  def convert(s: String): T
}

object Converter {
  def toConverter[T](converter: String => T): Converter[T] = new Converter[T] {
    override def convert(s: String): T = converter(s)
  }

  implicit val intConverter = toConverter(_.toInt)
  implicit val doubleConverter = toConverter(_.toDouble)
}
```

Then you can rewrite your method like this:

```
val map = Map("offset" -> "10", "price" -> "9.99")

def getQueryStringAs[T : Converter](key: String): Option[T] = {
  val converter = implicitly[Converter[T]]
  try {
    Some(converter convert map(key))
  } catch {
    case ex: Exception => None
  }
}
```

In use:

```
scala> getQueryStringAs[Int]("offset")
res1: Option[Int] = Some(10)

scala> getQueryStringAs[Double]("price")
res2: Option[Double] = Some(9.99)
```

Comment: I did get that warning, ignored it anyway. So, how should I go about doing it? Ideally, I should be able to call toT[Int], toT[Double] etc, and they should use the appropriate unapply.