# How to get around this scala compiler erasure warning?

Tags: scala

I am trying to compile this scala code and getting the following compiler warnings.

```
scala> val props: Map[String, _] = 
 |   x match {
 |     case t: Tuple2[String, _] => {
 |       val prop =
 |       t._2 match {
 |         case f: Function[_, _] => "hello"
 |         case s:Some[Function[_, _]] => "world"
 |         case _ => t._2
 |       }
 |     Map(t._1 -> prop)
 |   }
 |   case _ => null
 | }
<console>:10: warning: non-variable type argument String in type pattern (String, _) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
       case t: Tuple2[String, _] => {
               ^
<console>:14: warning: non-variable type argument _ => _ in type pattern Some[_ => _] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
           case s:Some[Function[_, _]] => "world"
                  ^
```

The answers given on [How do I get around type erasure on Scala? Or, why can't I get the type parameter of my collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramet) seems to point to this same issue. But I couldn't infer a solution in this particular context.

Comment: x could be anything like an Any object or function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `case t @ (_: String, _)` instead of `case t: Tuple2[String, _]` and `case s @ Some(_: Function[_, _])` instead of `case s:Some[Function[_, _]]`.

Scala cannot `match` on type parameters.

Comment: case t: WrappedArray[Tuple2[String, _]] => { -- also generates the same type erasure warning. Can you point me to why it is so?

Comment: @sobychacko It's so because of type erasure: in `jvm` in runtime `WrappedArray[(String, Int)]` and `WrappedArray[String]` are the same: `WrappedArray[Object]`. Information about type parameters is available only in compile time. See [this](http://www.scalafied.com/60/lightweight-type-erasure-matching) for some links and workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I would rewrite it like this:

```
x match {
  case (name, method) => {
    val prop =
      method match {
        case f: Function[_, _] => "hello"
        case Some(f: Function[_, _]) => "world"
        case other => other
      }

    Map(name -> prop)
  }
  case _ => null
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I liked both of the approaches.