# Access to nested map's values

Tags: scala

I have a Map

```
val m = Map(1->13, 2->Map(3->444, 4-> List("aaa", "bbb")))
```

I want to get its nested values:

```
// these all lead to an error
m.get(2)(3)
m.get(2).get(3)
m.get(2).get.get(3)
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Your problem comes from the fact that inside your map you're mixing values of heterogenous types (some are maps, others aren't) so your Map is interpreted as Map[Int,Any] (because Any is the common root in the type hierarchy for Int and Map.) Since Any does not have a "get" method or an "apply" method it all ends up with an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have [lost type information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete).

You could actually do what you want, but it's not typesafe.

```
m.get(2).flatMap{ case m2: Map[Int, _] => m2.get(3) }
```

Since you have lost type information you have to cast explicitly, so if you want to get list's element you should do something like this:

```
m.get(2).flatMap{ case m2: Map[Int, _] => m2.get(4) }.map{ case l: List[_] => l(1) }
```

You should try to save type information. At least you could use `Either`.

Comment: At last one can use adhoc class

Comment: what I want to get List's 2nd element, how do I do that?

Comment: @om-nom-nom: Type parameters are not the biggest problem here. The whole idea of storing `Int` and `Map` in the same container is evil.

Comment: @senia I understand :-) but if one badly needs such scheme, this might be an option.

Comment: @MariusKavansky: I've updated my answer, but i think you really should try save type information somehow. Scala is a typesafe language, you should not abuse it like this.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `map` which has inconsistent types of `key-value` pairs. Hence there cannot be one generalized answer.

Firstly `m.get(2)` returns an `Option[Any]`. Doing `m.get(2)(3)` is basically trying to do:

```
val option = m.get(2) //option is of type Option[Any]
option(3) //error
```

Hence you need to do:

```
m.get(2) match {
case Some(i) => i match {
     case j:Map[Any,Any] => j(3)
     }
 }
```

Something of this sort.