# Scala's "clean up" of type erasure

Tags: scala, compilation, jvm, type-erasure

I have just begun investigating Scala and found the following perplexing quote in the [Wikipedia page on Scala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29):

> [Scala] cleans up [...] poor design decisions in Java (e.g. type erasure...

I thought type erasure was a limitation imposed by the Java Virtual Machine, so given that the JVM executes Scala code, how has this been "cleaned up"?

I do appreciate that the designer of Scala also contributed to the JVM, so I am curious to understand if he / the Scala team has augmented the Scala compiler to carry rich run-time type information and thus 'clean up' type erasure. Is this the case?

Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala unfortunately still has to deal with type erasure at runtime in the JVM. However, a couple of things have been cleaned up with respect to generics:

- Type parameters are non-optional (no `List`, only `List<String>`/`List[String]`)
- Language support for co-/contravariance

Further, to deal with the limitations of the JVM [`TypeTags`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.api.TypeTags%24TypeTag) (in 2.9 [`Manifests`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.Manifest)) can be used to store type information that would otherwise be lost at runtime. For example:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def foo[T : TypeTag](x: List[T]) = {
  println(implicitly[TypeTag[T]].tpe)
}
```

This prints the type of the elements of the list. Something which would be irrecoverably lost, if - for example - you pass an empty list:

```
foo(List.empty[String])
// not distinguishable without TypeTags from
foo(List.empty[Int])
```

Comment: Many thanks for these insights! This answer is succinct and illuminating.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the quote says “cleans up”, not “eliminates”. Type erasure is still there and it can bite you.

Scala has `Manifest`s. `Manifest` is an *object* containing information about your actual type. [Here is a nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1094214/603094) about `Manifest`s.