# Why no Type Erasure Warning

Tags: scala

After reading this excellent [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete) on `type erasure` in Scala, I tried this code. The Scala compiler did not output a `type erasure` warning.

```
scala> val x: List[Int] = List(1,2,3)
x: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> x match {
     |   case List(x: Int) => println("a")
     |   case _ => println("false")
     |  }
false
```

Why doesn't the above code output the same warning as this code:

```
scala> List(1,2,3) match {
     |  case l: List[String] => println("list of strings")
     |  case _ => println("ok")
     | }
<console>:9: warning: fruitless type test: a value of type List[Int] cannot 
also be a List[String] (but still might match its erasure)
                   case l: List[String] => println("list of strings")
                           ^
    list of strings
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first case is not just testing type - it's testing by pattern-match that the list has exactly one integer element.