# Pattern matching on List[T] and Set[T] in Scala vs. Haskell: effects of type erasure

Tags: scala, haskell, pattern-matching, type-erasure, erasure

Would the Haskell equivalent of the code below produce correct answers?

Can this Scala code be fixed to produce correct answers ? If yes, how ?

```
object TypeErasurePatternMatchQuestion extends App {
  val li=List(1,2,3)
  val ls=List("1","2","3")
  val si=Set(1,2,3)
  val ss=Set("1","2","3")
  def whatIsIt(o:Any)=o match{
    case o:List[Int]    => "List[Int]"
    case o:List[String] => "List[String]"
    case o:Set[Int]     => "Set[Int]"
    case o:Set[String]     => "Set[String]"
  }

  println(whatIsIt(li))
  println(whatIsIt(ls))
  println(whatIsIt(si))
  println(whatIsIt(ss))

}
```

prints:

```
List[Int]
List[Int]
Set[Int]
Set[Int]
```

but I would expect it to print:

```
List[Int]
List[String]
Set[Int]
Set[String]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get around type erasure on Scala? Or, why can't I get the type parameter of my collections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I just wanted to mention it myself :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete?rq=1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must understand that by saying `o:Any` you erase all the specific information about the type and further on the type `Any` is all that the compiler knows about value `o`. That's why from that point on you can only rely on the runtime information about the type.

The case-expressions like `case o:List[Int]` are resolved using the JVM's special `instanceof` runtime mechanism. However the buggy behaviour you experience is caused by this mechanism only taking the first-rank type into account (the `List` in `List[Int]`) and ignoring the parameters (the `Int` in `List[Int]`). That's why it treats `List[Int]` as equal to `List[String]`. This issue is known as "Generics Erasure".

Haskell on the other hand performs a complete type erasure, which is well explained in the [answer by Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22392355/485115).

So the problem in both languages is the same: we need to provide a runtime information about the type and its parameters.

**In Scala** you can achieve that using the "reflection" library, which resolves that information implicitly:

```
import reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
def whatIsIt[T](o : T)(implicit t : ru.TypeTag[T]) = 
  if( t.tpe <:< ru.typeOf[List[Int]] ) 
    "List[Int]"
  else if ( t.tpe <:< ru.typeOf[List[String]] ) 
    "List[String]"
  else if ( t.tpe <:< ru.typeOf[Set[Int]] ) 
    "Set[Int]"
  else if ( t.tpe <:< ru.typeOf[Set[String]] ) 
    "Set[String]"
  else sys.error("Unexpected type")  

println(whatIsIt(List("1","2","3")))
println(whatIsIt(Set("1","2","3")))
```

Output:

```
List[String]
Set[String]
```

**Haskell** has a very different approach to polymorphism. Above all, it does not have subtype polymorphism (it's not a weakness though), that's why the type-switching pattern matches as in your example are simply irrelevant. However it is possible to translate the Scala solution from above into Haskell quite closely:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.Dynamic
import Data.Set

whatIsIt :: Dynamic -> String
whatIsIt a = 
  if | Just (_ :: [Int]) <- fromDynamic a -> "[Int]"
     | Just (_ :: [String]) <- fromDynamic a -> "[String]"
     | Just (_ :: Set Int) <- fromDynamic a -> "Set Int"
     | Just (_ :: Set String) <- fromDynamic a -> "Set String"
     | otherwise -> error "Unexpected type"

main = do
  putStrLn $ whatIsIt $ toDyn ([1, 2, 3] :: [Int])
  putStrLn $ whatIsIt $ toDyn (["1", "2", "3"] :: [String])
  putStrLn $ whatIsIt $ toDyn (Data.Set.fromList ["1", "2", "3"] :: Set String)
```

Output:

```
[Int]
[String]
Set String
```

However I must outline boldly that **this is far from a typical scenario of Haskell programming**. The language's type-system is powerful enough to solve extremely intricate problems while maintaining all the type-level information (and safety). `Dynamic` is only used in very special cases in low-level libraries.

Answer (score 5):

GHC does even more type erasure than the JVM; at runtime the types are *completely* gone (not just the type parameters).

Haskell's approach to types is to use them at compile time to **guarantee** that no ill-typed operation can ever be carried out, and since Haskell doesn't have OO-style subtyping and dynamic dispatch, there's no purpose at all to keeping the types around. So data is compiled to a memory structure that simply contains the right values, and functions are compiled with baked-in knowledge of the structure of the types on which they operate<sup>1</sup>, and just blindly expect their arguments to have that structure. That's why you get fun things like segmentation faults if you mess with `unsafeCoerce` incorrectly, not just a runtime exception saying the value was not of the expected type; at runtime Haskell *has no idea* whether a value is of any given type.

So rather than Haskell giving "the right answer" to the equivalent program, Haskell *disallows* your program as unsafe! There is no `Any` type in Haskell to which you can cast whatever you want.

That's not 100% true; in both Haskell and Scala there are ways of keeping type information alive at runtime. Essentially it's done by creating ordinary data structures that *represent* types, and passing them around together values that are of those types, so at runtime you can refer to the type representation object for information about the type of the other object. There are library and language facilities in both languages to let you use this mechanism at a higher (and more principled) level, so that it's easier to use safely. Because it requires the type tokens to be passed around, you have to "opt-in" to such features, and your callers have to be aware of it to pass you the required type tokens (whether the actual generation and passing of the token is done implicitly or explicitly).

Without using such features, Haskell provides no way to pattern match on a value that could be of type `List Int` or `Set String` to find out which one it is. Either you're using a monomorphic type, in which case it can only *be* one type and the others will be rejected, or you're using a polymorphic type, in which case you can only apply code to it that will do the same thing<sup>2</sup> *regardless* of which concrete type instantiates the polymorphic type.

---

<sup>1</sup> Except for polymorphic functions, which assume *nothing* about their polymorphic arguments, and so can basically do nothing with them except pass them to other polymorphic functions (with matching type class constraints, if any).

<sup>2</sup> Type class constrained polymorphic types are the only exception to this. Even then, if you've got a value a type that's a member of some type class, all you can do with it is pass it to other functions that accept values in *any* type that is a member of that type class. And if those functions are general functions defined outside of the type class in question, they'll be under the same restriction. It's only the type class methods themselves that can actually "do something different" for different types in the class, and that's because they are the union of a whole bunch of *monomorphic* definitions that operate on one particular type in the class. You can't write code that gets to take a polymorphic value, inspect it to see what it was instantiated with, and then decide what to do.

Answer (score 3):

Of course Haskell prints the right answer:

```
import Data.Set
import Data.Typeable

main = do
  let li=[1,2,3]
  let ls=["1","2","3"]
  let si=Data.Set.fromList[1,2,3]
  let ss=Data.Set.fromList["1","2","3"]
  print $ typeOf li
  print $ typeOf ls
  print $ typeOf si
  print $ typeOf ss
```

prints

```
[Integer]
[[Char]]
Set Integer
Set [Char]
```

Comment: Thanks, so the pattern match approach would work too in Haskell ?

Comment: It's worth noting that `Data.Typeable` is arguably pretty strongly against the spirit of Haskell, which does have type erasure and doesn't provide type cases in its pattern matching.

Comment: So you cannot write the same pattern match correctly in Haskell either?

Comment: You can write a very similar pattern matching in Haskell.  But again, it uses `Data.Typeable`, because Haskell has even more type erasure than Scala/Java.  But `Data.Typeable` makes it accessible again.